# How can I select random files from a directory in bash?

Tags: bash, random

I have a directory with about 2000 files. How can I select a random sample of `N` files through using either a bash script or a list of piped commands?

Comment: Also a good answer at Unix&Linux : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38344/24170

Comment: `ls | shuf -n 5` [Source from Unix Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48477/14993)

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-on-the-unix-command-line-or-in-a-shel

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Here's a script that uses GNU sort's random option:

```
ls |sort -R |tail -$N |while read file; do
    # Something involving $file, or you can leave
    # off the while to just get the filenames
done
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know sort -R; I used  bogosort previously :-p

Comment: sort: invalid option -- R
Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for files that have spaces in them.

Comment: This should work for files with spaces (the pipeline processes lines). It doesn't work for names with newline in them. Only the use of `"$file"`, not shown, would be sensitive to spaces.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: That won't work for file names that include backslashes since `read` without `-r` will strip them. It also won't work for spaces at the start or end of the file names since those are stripped by `read` unless `IFS` is null. Using `tail` for this is potentially far less efficient than `head` would be since the former has to wait until `sort -R` has produced all of it's output before going back N lines from the end while the latter can stop processing and kill `sort -R` after it outputs it's first N lines.

Answer (score 152):

You can use `shuf` (from the GNU coreutils package) for that. Just feed it a list of file names and ask it to return the first line from a random permutation:

```
ls dirname | shuf -n 1
# probably faster and more flexible:
find dirname -type f | shuf -n 1
# etc..
```

Adjust the `-n, --head-count=COUNT` value to return the number of wanted lines. For example to return 5 random filenames you would use:

```
find dirname -type f | shuf -n 5
```

Comment: OP wanted to select `N` random files, so using `1` is a bit misleading.

Comment: If you have filenames with newlines: `find dirname -type f -print0 | shuf -zn1`

Comment: what if I have to copy these randomly selected files to an another folder? how to perform operations on these randomly selected files?

Comment: Can it open its full path direcyory as well?

Comment: If you want the full path use:  `find "$(pwd)" | shuf -n 1`

Comment: Just a note that if you're using a Mac with OS X and `zsh`, the GNU `shuf` command may not be installed.  So you'd have to install shuf first, or just use Josh Lee's method.

Comment: I ended up using this in my `random-file` in the BashScripts Collection: https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/e3d432edc29d8c5494bd4f5f034d25c8238fa56a/random-file#L21

Answer (score 22):

Here are a few possibilities that don't parse the output of `ls` and that are 100% safe regarding files with spaces and funny symbols in their name. All of them will populate an array `randf` with a list of random files. This array is easily printed with `printf '%s\n' "${randf[@]}"` if needed.

- This one will possibly output the same file several times, and `N` needs to be known in advance. Here I chose N=42.

  ```
  a=( * )
  randf=( "${a[RANDOM%${#a[@]}]"{1..42}"}" )
  ```

  This feature is not very well documented.
- If N is not known in advance, but you really liked the previous possibility, you can use `eval`. But it's evil, and you must really make sure that `N` doesn't come directly from user input without being thoroughly checked!

  ```
  N=42
  a=( * )
  eval randf=( \"\${a[RANDOM%\${#a[@]}]\"\{1..$N\}\"}\" )
  ```

  *I personally dislike `eval` and hence this answer!*
- The same using a more straightforward method (a loop):

  ```
  N=42
  a=( * )
  randf=()
  for((i=0;i<N;++i)); do
      randf+=( "${a[RANDOM%${#a[@]}]}" )
  done
  ```
- If you don't want to possibly have several times the same file:

  ```
  N=42
  a=( * )
  randf=()
  for((i=0;i<N && ${#a[@]};++i)); do
      ((j=RANDOM%${#a[@]}))
      randf+=( "${a[j]}" )
      a=( "${a[@]:0:j}" "${a[@]:j+1}" )
  done
  ```

*Note*. This is a late answer to an old post, but the accepted answer links to an external page that shows terrible [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) practice, and the other answer is not much better as it also parses the output of `ls`. A comment to the accepted answer points to an excellent answer by Lhunath which obviously shows good practice, but doesn't exactly answer the OP.

Comment: First and second produced "bad substitution"; it didn't like the `"{1..42}"` part leaving a trailing `"1"`. Also, `$RANDOM` is only 15 bit and the method will not work with over 32767 files to choose from.

Answer (score 19):

```
ls | shuf -n 10 # ten random files
```

Comment: You shouldn’t rely on the output of `ls`. This won’t work if e.g. a filename contains newlines.

Comment: @bfontaine you seem haunted by newlines in file names :). Are they really that common? In other words, is there some tool that creates files with newlines in their name? Since as a user it is very difficult to create such a filename. Same for files coming from the internet

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga That’s an example of the issues you might get. `ls` isn’t guaranteed to give you "clean" filenames so you shouldn’t rely on it, period. The fact that these issues are rare or unusual doesn’t change the problem; especially given there are better solutions for this.

Comment: `ls` may include directories and blank lines. I would suggest something like `find . -type f | shuf -n10` instead.

Comment: This does not return the files's full path

Comment: @cherdt also `-maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution for selecting `5` random files while [avoiding to parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It also works with files containing spaces, newlines and other special characters:

```
shuf -ezn 5 * | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

Replace `echo` with the command you want to execute for your files.

Comment: well, doesn't the pipe + `read` have the same problems as parsing `ls`? namely, it reads line by line, so it doesn't work for files with newlines in their name

Comment: You are right. My previous solution didn't work for file names containing newlines and probably breaks on others with certain special characters, too. I've updated my answer to use null-termination instead of newlines.

Comment: i like it. `shuf -ezn 10 ${RAWDATA_DIR}/* | xargs -0 -n1 echo `. Thanks

Comment: note this solution also selects directories

Answer (score 7):

This is an even later response to @gniourf_gniourf's late answer, which I just upvoted because it's by far the best answer, twice over. (Once for avoiding `eval` and once for safe filename handling.)

But it took me a few minutes to untangle the "not very well documented" feature(s) this answer uses. If your Bash skills are solid enough that you saw immediately how it works, then skip this comment. But I didn't, and having untangled it I think it's worth explaining.

**Feature #1** is the shell's own file globbing. `a=(*)` creates an array, `$a`, whose members are the files in the current directory. Bash understands all the weirdnesses of filenames, so that list is guaranteed correct, guaranteed escaped, etc. No need to worry about properly parsing textual file names returned by `ls`.

**Feature #2** is Bash [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for [arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays), one nested within another. This starts with `${#ARRAY[@]}`, which expands to the length of `$ARRAY`.

That expansion is then used to subscript the array. The standard way to find a random number between 1 and N is to take the value of random number modulo N. We want a random number between 0 and the length of our array. Here's the approach, broken into two lines for clarity's sake:

```
LENGTH=${#ARRAY[@]}
RANDOM=${a[RANDOM%$LENGTH]}
```

But this solution does it in a single line, removing the unnecessary variable assignment.

**Feature #3** is [Bash brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), although I have to confess I don't entirely understand it. Brace expansion is used, for instance, to generate a list of 25 files named `filename1.txt`, `filename2.txt`, etc: `echo "filename"{1..25}".txt"`.

The expression inside the subshell above, `"${a[RANDOM%${#a[@]}]"{1..42}"}"`, uses that trick to produce 42 separate expansions. The brace expansion places a single digit in between the `]` and the `}`, which at first I thought was subscripting the array, but if so it would be preceded by a colon. (It would also have returned 42 consecutive items from a random spot in the array, which is not at all the same thing as returning 42 random items from the array.) I think it's just making the shell run the expansion 42 times, thereby returning 42 random items from the array. (But if someone can explain it more fully, I'd love to hear it.)

The reason N has to be hardcoded (to 42) is that brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

Finally, here's **Feature #4**, if you want to do this recursively for a directory hierarchy:

```
shopt -s globstar
a=( ** )
```

This turns on a [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) that causes `**` to match recursively. Now your `$a` array contains every file in the entire hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to copy a sample of those files to another folder:

```
ls | shuf -n 100 | xargs -I % cp % ../samples/
```

make samples directory first obviously.

Comment: Defining a file extension helps : `ls dir/*.jpeg | shuf -n 100 | xargs -I % cp % ../samples/`

Answer (score 4):

If you have Python installed (works with either Python 2 or Python 3):

To select one file (or line from an arbitrary command), use

```
ls -1 | python -c "import sys; import random; print(random.choice(sys.stdin.readlines()).rstrip())"
```

To select `N` files/lines, use (note `N` is at the end of the command, replace this by a number)

```
ls -1 | python -c "import sys; import random; print(''.join(random.sample(sys.stdin.readlines(), int(sys.argv[1]))).rstrip())" N
```

Comment: This doesn’t work if your filename contains newlines.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS does not have the *sort -R* and *shuf* commands, so I needed a bash only solution that randomizes all files **without duplicates** and did not find that here. This solution is similar to gniourf_gniourf's solution #4, but hopefully adds better comments.

The script should be easy to modify to stop after N samples using a counter with if, or gniourf_gniourf's for loop with N. $RANDOM is limited to ~32000 files, but that should do for most cases.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(*)  # this is the array of files to shuffle
# echo ${array[@]}
for dummy in "${array[@]}"; do  # do loop length(array) times; once for each file
    length=${#array[@]}
    randomi=$(( $RANDOM % $length ))  # select a random index

    filename=${array[$randomi]}
    echo "Processing: '$filename'"  # do something with the file

    unset -v "array[$randomi]"  # set the element at index $randomi to NULL
    array=("${array[@]}")  # remove NULL elements introduced by unset; copy array
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more files in your folder, you can use the below piped command I found in unix [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411400).

```
find /some/dir/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 8 -z | xargs -0 cp -vt /target/dir/
```

Here I wanted to copy the files, but if you want to move files or do something else, just change the last command where I have used `cp`.

Comment: I ran this command and thought that "8" is the desired number of files, but 88 were copied...

Answer (score 1):

This is the only script I can get to play nice with bash on MacOS. I combined and edited snippets from the following two links:

[ls command: how can I get a recursive full-path listing, one line per file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/is-there-a-bash-command-for-picking-a-random-file-678687/

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reads a given directory and picks a random file.

# The directory you want to use. You could use "$1" instead if you
# wanted to parametrize it.
DIR="/path/to/"
# DIR="$1"

# Internal Field Separator set to newline, so file names with
# spaces do not break our script.
IFS='
'

if [[ -d "${DIR}" ]]
then
  # Runs ls on the given dir, and dumps the output into a matrix,
  # it uses the new lines character as a field delimiter, as explained above.
  #  file_matrix=($(ls -LR "${DIR}"))

  file_matrix=($(ls -R $DIR | awk '; /:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}; /:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}; NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }'))
  num_files=${#file_matrix[*]}

  # This is the command you want to run on a random file.
  # Change "ls -l" by anything you want, it's just an example.
  ls -l "${file_matrix[$((RANDOM%num_files))]}"
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this: it uses temporary file but goes deeply in a directory until it find a regular file and return it.

```
# find for a quasi-random file in a directory tree:

# directory to start search from:
ROOT="/";  

tmp=/tmp/mytempfile    
TARGET="$ROOT"
FILE=""; 
n=
r=
while [ -e "$TARGET" ]; do 
    TARGET="$(readlink -f "${TARGET}/$FILE")" ; 
    if [ -d "$TARGET" ]; then
      ls -1 "$TARGET" 2> /dev/null > $tmp || break;
      n=$(cat $tmp | wc -l); 
      if [ $n != 0 ]; then
        FILE=$(shuf -n 1 $tmp)
# or if you dont have/want to use shuf:
#       r=$(($RANDOM % $n)) ; 
#       FILE=$(tail -n +$(( $r + 1 ))  $tmp | head -n 1); 
      fi ; 
    else
      if [ -f "$TARGET"  ] ; then
        rm -f $tmp
        echo $TARGET
        break;
      else 
        # is not a regular file, restart:
        TARGET="$ROOT"
        FILE=""
      fi
    fi
done;
```

Answer (score -1):

How about a Perl solution slightly doctored from Mr. Kang over here:
 [How can I shuffle the lines of a text file on the Unix command line or in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-on-the-unix-command-line-or-in-a-shel)

> $ ls | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e '@lines = shuffle(<>); print
>   @lines[0..4]'