# How can I get a recursive full-path listing, one line per file?

Tags: bash, command-line, find, ls

How can I spit out a flat list of recursive one-per-line paths?

For example, I just want a flat listing of files with their full paths:

```
/home/dreftymac/.
/home/dreftymac/foo.txt
/home/dreftymac/bar.txt
/home/dreftymac/stackoverflow
/home/dreftymac/stackoverflow/alpha.txt
/home/dreftymac/stackoverflow/bravo.txt
/home/dreftymac/stackoverflow/charlie.txt
```

`ls -a1` almost does what I need, but I do not want path fragments, I want full paths.

Comment: **See also:** [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455675/42223)

Comment: tree -aflix --noreport <path> but if you use tree and there are any symbolic links in the path you will have to deal with those or use an alternate solution from one of the suggested answers.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

If you really want to use `ls`, then format its output using awk:

```
ls -R /path | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }'
```

Comment: <3 this command...perfect solution for what I need right now! thank you!

Comment: Can someone please explain the above `awk` expressions?

Comment: A bit late too. Indeed: how would symbolic links be handled in these cases? As I was thinking about this for an "home made" index of files, somewhat like locate on a single file list. But if I could get the full path, as it is indeed my files, it makes sense (to me) to show me the actual ls output, mainly I guess, dates and full path.

Comment: The target would be: get the 12 or more old HD i have (full HD), make a full path 'ls' output, and use it for some fast 'grep' searching. It makes little sense to back them up, as it is loads of probably already duplicated data. Maybe there is some catalog alike tool but I am not sure if a simple grep for when I need it is better. I mean: a full backup system vs a couple of files...

Comment: This solution doesn't omit the directories (each directory gets its own line)

Comment: Use it carefully !!! As said above it also list all directories and the `roots` directories as well so if you plan to use it to delete a list of files you need to clean this list !

Comment: Thanks.  Btw, would be nice to have this in 1 line for quick copy & paste.

Comment: add this to your [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do) file:
`function lsr () {
  ls -R "$@" | awk '
  /:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
  /:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
  NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }'
}`
so you can use `lsr /path` to use this wherever

Comment: The other answer should be accepted. This is a good second answer and does indeed answer the question as written, but the best solution is the one using `find`. The intention of the question is clear (which is not that it has to done using `ls`), and this answer is better only for those who can't use `find`. The claim this answer is more "right" because it answers the *written* question instead of the *intended* one is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: The correct answer is that you can't. This is just a waste of time.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the `awk` code? It looks like you are using a regex to catch lines that end in ":" (the "headers" with parent directory paths), but I get lost after that and definitely don't understand the part where the last field `NF` is being evaluated as true/false. Thanks!

Comment: The NF eval is for checking whether the line is blank. It could be replaced with /^$/ for example, but NF is computed anyways. I simplified the awk code as follows, as the provided version is buggy as it omits files at the top-level directory (I edited the answer, but not sure if my edits will be approved): `ls -R | awk '/:$/ {sub(/:$/,""); s=$0;next}{ print s "/" $0 }' `

Answer (score 748):

Use find:

```
find .
find /home/dreftymac
```

If you want files only (omit directories, devices, etc):

```
find . -type f
find /home/dreftymac -type f
```

Comment: can `ls` parameters like `--sort=extension` "redeemed" by this solution?

Comment: You can even use printf output in order to display needed contextual info (e.g. find . -type f -printf '%p %u\n')

Comment: Can this be formatted with a falg?  ie. python pprint.pprint(files)

Comment: But `find` does not print file sizes :( I want `ls -alR` but I want each line to contain full path.

Comment: @Shayan `find` with the `-printf` predicate allows you to do everyting `ls` does, and then some. However, it is not standard. You can use `find -exec stat {} \;` but unfortunately the options to `stat` are not standardized, either.

Comment: ... In the end, unfortunately, the most portable solution might be a Perl or Python script.

Comment: Thank for this.. I'll use `find \`pwd\`` to list evertthing from the current location, with full absolute paths.

Comment: `find . -type f -printf '%BF_%BH:%BM %p\n'`  gives a nice output with date first like `2019-03-18_10:15 /path/to/file`  (gnu find has printf, not all do)

Answer (score 92):

`ls -ld $(find .)`

if you want to sort your output by modification time:

`ls -ltd $(find .)`

Comment: -bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Comment: +1 worked for me with 12106 files, and I could use the `--sort=extension` parameter of `ls`

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have thought by myself of that (nice and short) syntax - i would have used `find . -name "*" -exec ls -ld '{}' \;` (that one works whatever the number of files is), but your command is way shorter to write ;)

Comment: ls -ld $(find .) 
breaks for me if I'm listing a ntfs disk where files have spaces: 
ls: cannot access ./System: No such file or directory

however find with quotes by @SRG works

Comment: A shorter alternative (depending on your needs) would be `find . -ls`.

Comment: SRG modified to `find . -name "*" -exec ls -ld -w1 -Q -x '{}' \;` shows file names only and quotes everything for ntfs space characters.

Answer (score 71):

Best command is: `tree -fi`

-f print the full path prefix for each file
-i don't print indentations

e.g.

```
$ tree -fi
.
./README.md
./node_modules
./package.json
./src
./src/datasources
./src/datasources/bookmarks.js
./src/example.json
./src/index.js
./src/resolvers.js
./src/schema.js
```

In order to use the files but not the links, you have to remove `>` from your output:

```
tree -fi |grep -v \>
```

If you want to know the nature of each file, (to read only ASCII files for example) try a `while` loop:

```
tree -fi |
grep -v \> |
while read -r first ; do 
    file "${first}"
done |
grep ASCII
```

Comment: @Nakilon what's the closest thing? Does it display output similarly? How would you _easily_ display similar output with a _short_ command?

Comment: @om01: on osx it is a difficult as `brew install tree`, given you are using homebrew

Comment: i couldn't list the files exclusivelty. it always lists the directories too. how can i do that?

Comment: @kommrad You could adapt the `file` example and pipe to `grep -v directory`

Answer (score 66):

Oh, really a long list of answers. 
It helped a lot and finally, I created my own which I was looking for :

To List All the Files in a directory and its sub-directories:

```
find "$PWD" -type f
```

To List All the Directories in a directory and its sub-directories:

```
find "$PWD" -type d
```

To List All the Directories and Files in a directory and its sub-directories:

```
find "$PWD"
```

Comment: And to filter by extension: `find "$PWD" -type f | grep '\.json$'`

Comment: No Need of post-processing with grep, use -name in find like:

      find "$PWD" -type f -name *.json

and if you want to delete the files listed :

      find "$PWD" -type f -name *.json -exec rm {} \;

similarly, if you want to copy it then replace rm with cp and destination:     -exec cp {} destination

Comment: must use "$PWD/" in my condition:
find "$PWD/" -type f;

Comment: And to list a particular file with its full path `find "$PWD/README.md"`

Answer (score 62):

Try the following simpler way:

```
find "$PWD"
```

Comment: `find "\`pwd\`"` if the path contains spaces or some other special characters.

Comment: How is this any different than `find .`? -.-

Comment: @SalmanPK If you give find an absolute path like `pwd` to start with, it will print absolute paths. By the way, "How is this any different than `find`" ;-)

Comment: `find` without an argument is a syntax error on some platforms. Where it isn't, just `find` is equivalent to `find .`.

Answer (score 23):

```
du -a
```

Handy for some limited appliance shells where find/locate aren't available.

Comment: any idea how I can remove the filesize wihtout `awk` ?

Answer (score 21):

I don't know about the full path, but you can use `-R` for recursion.  Alternatively, if you're not bent on `ls`, you can just do `find *`.

Answer (score 18):

Using no external commands other than ls:

```
ls -R1 /path | 
  while read l; do case $l in *:) d=${l%:};; "") d=;; *) echo "$d/$l";; esac; done
```

Comment: Unknown option '-1'. Aborting.

Comment: @ilw That's weird; I'd think `ls -1` is fairly [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html); but try just leaving it out if it's unsupported. The purpose of that option is to force `ls` to print one line per file but that's usually its behavior out of the box anyway. (But then of course, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) (Looking at the POSIX doco, this option was traditionally BSD only, but was introduced in POSIX in 2017.)

Comment: All the subfolders will be in the list, not just files.

Answer (score 14):

find / will do the trick

Answer (score 14):

Run a bash command with the following format:

```
find /path -type f -exec ls -l \{\} \;
```

Likewise, to trim away `-l` details and return only the absolute paths:

```
find /path -type f -exec ls \{\} \;
```

Comment: `find -ls`  avoids running an external process for each file and is a lot easier to type.

Comment: You don´t need the `-exec ls \{\} \;` part, since the default behavior of `find` is to print the full path. That is, `find /path -type f` does the job if you don´t need the file attributes from `ls -l`.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way for all you future people is simply:

```
du
```

This however, also shows the size of whats contained in each folder
You can use awk to output only the folder name:

```
du | awk '{print $2}'
```

Edit- Sorry sorry, my bad. I thought it was only folders that were needed.
Ill leave this here in case anyone in the future needs it anyways...

Comment: Interesting, because it shows me stuff I didn't know I wanted to know -- kind of like Google suggest.  It turns out, I like knowing how much space each file takes.

Answer (score 9):

With having the freedom of using all possible ls options:

`find -type f | xargs ls -1`

Answer (score 8):

I think for a flat list the best way is:

```
find -D tree /fullpath/to-dir/
```

(or in order to save it in a txt file)

```
find -D tree /fullpath/to-dir/ > file.txt
```

Comment: Tried on Mac OS 10.13.3.

`find: illegal option -- D`

Answer (score 7):

Adding a wildcard to the end of an ls directory forces full paths. Right now you have this:

```
$ ls /home/dreftymac/
foo.txt
bar.txt
stackoverflow
stackoverflow/alpha.txt
stackoverflow/bravo.txt
stackoverflow/charlie.txt
```

You could do this instead:

```
$ ls /home/dreftymac/*
/home/dreftymac/.
/home/dreftymac/foo.txt
/home/dreftymac/bar.txt
/home/dreftymac/stackoverflow:
alpha.txt
bravo.txt
charlie.txt
```

Unfortunately this does not print the full path for directories recursed into, so it may not be the full solution you're looking for.

Comment: Also unfortunately you can't sudo ls with a wildcard (because the wildcard is expanded as the normal user).

Comment: Also unfortunately, `ls` has a lot of pesky corner cases; see [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 7):

Don't make it complicated. I just used this and got a beautiful output:

```
ls -lR /path/I/need
```

Comment: OP wants just the full path and nothing else.  `ls -lR` wouldn't meet that goal.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't do it

Comment: Sorry man, doesn't fit the bill. If you need a list of full paths, you won't get it this way. At least not with bash or zsh on BSD or MacOS

Answer (score 6):

Here is a partial answer that shows the directory names.

```
ls -mR * | sed -n 's/://p'
```

Explanation:

`ls -mR *` lists the full directory names ending in a ':', then lists the files in that directory separately

`sed -n 's/://p'` finds lines that end in a colon, strip off the colon and print the line

By iterating over the list of directories, we should be able to find the directories as well. Still workin on it. It is a challenge to get the wildcards through xargs.

Answer (score 5):

The `realpath` command prints the resolved path:

```
realpath *
```

To include dot files, pipe the output of `ls -a` to realpath:

```
ls -a | xargs realpath
```

To list subdirectories recursively:

```
ls -aR | xargs realpath
```

In case you have spaces in file names, `man xargs` recommends using the `-o` option to prevent file names from being processed incorrectly, this works best with the output of `find -print0` and it starts to look a lot more complex than other answers:

```
find -print0 |xargs -0 realpath
```

See also Unix and Linux stackexchange [question on how to list all files in a directory with absolute path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268474/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory-with-absolute-paths).

Answer (score 4):

If the directory is passed as a relative path and you will need to convert it to an absolute path before calling find.  In the following example, the directory is passed as the first parameter to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get absolute path
directory=`cd $1; pwd`
# print out list of files and directories
find "$directory"
```

Comment: If your system has `readlink` you can do `directory=$(readlink -e $1)`

Comment: True, but cd/pwd combination will work on every system. 

`readlink` on OS X 10.5.8 does not support -e option.

Answer (score 4):

```
tar cf - $PWD|tar tvf -
```

This is slow but works recursively and prints both directories and files. You can pipe it with awk/grep if you just want the file names without all the other info/directories:

```
tar cf - $PWD|tar tvf -|awk '{print $6}'|grep -v "/$"
```

Comment: you can also use simply : tar cvf /dev/null $PWD

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers I see. This is mine, and I think quite useful if you are working on Mac.

I'm sure you know there are some "bundle" files (*.app*, *.rtfd*, *.workflow*, and so on). And looking at Finder's window they seem single files. But they are not. And `$ ls` or `$ find` see them as directories... So, unless you need list their contents as well, this works for me:

```
find . -not -name ".*" -not -name "." | egrep -v "\.rtfd/|\.app/|\.lpdf/|\.workflow/"
```

Of course this is for the working dir, and you could add other bundles' extensions (but always with a `/` after them). Or any other extensions if not bundle's without the `/`.

Rather interesting the "`.lpdf/`" (multilingual pdf). It has normal "`.pdf`" extension (!!) or none in Finder. This way you get (or it just counts 1 file) for this `pdf` and not a bunch of stuff…

Answer (score 4):

`ls -lR`  is what you were looking for, or atleast I was. cheers

Comment: OP wants just the full path and nothing else. `ls -lR` wouldn't meet that goal.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive list of all files from current location:

`ls -l $(find . -type f)`

Comment: Better yet `find . -type f -ls` which won't choke if the output from `find` is too long for `ls`

Answer (score 3):

If you have to search on a large disk like 100 Gb or more,
I suggest to do the command `tree` that [@kerkael posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192137/1461682) and not the `find` or `ls`.

I suggest that when you do the command `tree` you write the output in the file, different from the [@kerkael's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192137/1461682).

Example:

```
tree -fi > result.txt
```

Afterwards, do a `grep command` in file using a pattern like `grep -i "*.docx" > result.txt` so you do not lose time. This way is faster for searching file(s) on big disks.

I did these commands on a 270GB disk that I get a file `txt` taken 100MB.

The time that taken for command `tree` was 14 minutes.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

@ghostdog74:
Little tweak with your solution. 
Following code can be used to search file with its full absolute path.

```bash
sudo ls -R / | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' | grep [file_to_search]
```

Answer (score 2):

I knew the file name but wanted the directory as well.

```
find $PWD | fgrep filename
```

worked perfectly in Mac OS 10.12.1

Comment: Works like a charm, also on MacOS 10.15.7, in Terminal, using zsh as default shell. Wonderful, and thanks!

Comment: This is rather imprecise and inefficient. A better attempt is `find . -name filename`