# Linux command to print directory structure in the form of a tree

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there any linux command that I can call from a Bash script that will print the directory structure in the form of a tree, e.g.,

```
folder1
   a.txt
   b.txt
folder2
   folder3
```

Comment: Just run `find`. Or `find . -not -path '*/\.*'` to hide files and folders starting with `.`. If you want to have output with spaces, as in the question, use it with this "find prettifier" script: `find . -not -path '*/\.*' | python -c "import sys as s;s.a=[];[setattr(s,'a',list(filter(lambda p: c.startswith(p+'/'),s.a)))or (s.stdout.write('  '*len(s.a)+c[len(s.a[-1])+1 if s.a else 0:])or True) and s.a.append(c[:-1]) for c in s.stdin]"`

Comment: Shouldn't such questions get migrated to SuperUser rather than closed ?

Comment: @Balmipour: Perhaps they should. But "Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated" ([What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/248863)). Don't ask me why.

Comment: i dont think this question deserves to be closed as "off topic". The tags seem to be right.

Comment: The policy of closing questions without migrating is harmful to both stackoverflow and human knowledge in general.

In the last 3 days, every single questions I googled and came across was closed for similar reasoning, and no more activity was able to happen. This means no one can update it, no one can give a better answer, and it makes stackoverflow look shortsighted or elitist. Stackoverflow should consider requiring a migration when a topic is found to have these conditions.

Comment: I agree with @NickYeates I am here in late September of 2017 still finding answers to this same question.  Think long term when we design these question and answer policies!

Comment: While this kind of questions probably belongs more to Serverfault than SO, I don't get the point of closing interesting posts.  It is clear and tagged correctly.  Do such questions get closed because the utility used to print a tree is `tree`, which seems too obvious ?  If it was, the questions and answer wouldn't get hundreds of votes.  This result is google's favorite on the topic, please, reopen, so that we can give some better answers !

Answer (score 1011, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)? It should be in most distributions (maybe as an optional install).

```
~> tree -d /proc/self/
/proc/self/
|-- attr
|-- cwd -> /proc
|-- fd
|   `-- 3 -> /proc/15589/fd
|-- fdinfo
|-- net
|   |-- dev_snmp6
|   |-- netfilter
|   |-- rpc
|   |   |-- auth.rpcsec.context
|   |   |-- auth.rpcsec.init
|   |   |-- auth.unix.gid
|   |   |-- auth.unix.ip
|   |   |-- nfs4.idtoname
|   |   |-- nfs4.nametoid
|   |   |-- nfsd.export
|   |   `-- nfsd.fh
|   `-- stat
|-- root -> /
`-- task
    `-- 15589
        |-- attr
        |-- cwd -> /proc
        |-- fd
        | `-- 3 -> /proc/15589/task/15589/fd
        |-- fdinfo
        `-- root -> /

27 directories
```

sample taken from maintainer's web page.

You can add the option `-L #` where `#` is replaced by a number, to specify the max recursion depth.

Remove `-d` to display also files.

Comment: Note for any visitor seeing this: remove `-d` to display files also!

Comment: Note for any visitor seeing this: The man page lists a truckload of more flags for you :)

Comment: Note for any visitor seeing this: I couldn't get `tree` to count the number of files inside any directory, so I wrote https://github.com/fiatjaf/tree-dir, which is the same as `tree -d`, but does this (also doesn't have colours).

Comment: To install on Mac OS X w/Homebrew:  `brew install tree`

Comment: To install on cygwin `apt-cyg install tree` (assuming you've installed apt-cyg)

Comment: Not built in. I need something portable.

Comment: since there are examples for [apt-get](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/apt/apt-get/), [brew](http://brew.sh/), [yum](http://linuxwiki.de/yum), [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) etc. i will also add [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman) `pacman -S tree`

Comment: `tree` wasn't installed on Debian 8 Jessie by default. `apt install tree` to get it.

Comment: Not even Ubuntu 16.04 comes with this. Use `apt-get install tree` will install it.

Comment: You can install this with brew in linux also
- install http://linuxbrew.sh/
- then `brew install tree`

Comment: @blockloop Thanks for that excellent tip!  I never knew about `apt-cyg`, and was always annoyed about the very minor `setup.ini` version changes the usual installer always complained about, and frequently!  Also, the usual installer installed `tree` `1.7.0-1`, but it did not work.  Although `apt-cyg` worked!  Windows 10 Pro x64-bit.  For the installer, maybe I had the paths wrong, but I only see my 1 Cygwin folder where I expect to see it, and where the install said as well..

Comment: The `-s` option can be added for displaying the *size information*.

Comment: To install in Linux CentOS 6, you can use `yum install tree`

Comment: to install on mac `port install tree`

Comment: If you cannot install tree like me because of org permission use this:                                                              
                  find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for (on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS). Many thanks! Upvoted

Comment: I found this link to install tree on WIndows for use in Git Bash: https://comprostack.netlify.app/tools/cmd/add-tree-command-to-git-bash-on-windows/#:~:text=Add%20tree%20command%20manually%20Download%20Tree%20for%20Windows,bash%20will%20be%20ready%20to%20use%20tree%20command.

Comment: Not installed with Pop!_OS 22.04, which kinda surprised me. apt install tree is easy enough though!

Answer (score 461):

You can use this one:

```sh
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

It will show a graphical representation of the current sub-directories without files **in a few seconds**, e.g. in <kbd>/var/cache/</kbd>:

```
   .
   |-apache2
   |---mod_cache_disk
   |-apparmor
   |-apt
   |---archives
   |-----partial
   |-apt-xapian-index
   |---index.1
   |-dbconfig-common
   |---backups
   |-debconf
```

[Source](https://centerkey.com/tree/)

Comment: If you want it with spaces, more like the OP requested, then this:

     `ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//  /g' -e 's/^/   /'`

Comment: any way I can make this ignore dotfiles? E.g. prevent it from listing the contents of `.git`?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree#comment37392136_3455625)

Comment: with files:    `find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"`

Comment: Is it possible to ignore a specific directory?

Comment: @Ben thanks for that, all other (non-`tree`) answers produce a result that does not look perfectly correct to me. For example in this answer, there should be a line going down from `apt` then horizontally to `archives`, instead it comes down from `.` and goes to `archives`, only because of more indentation you can guess that it's actually a subfolder of `apt`. So you could as well just leave the lines away, it's at least not misleading then.

Comment: Nice but it takes very long time if you have very much files in that folder.

Comment: Very useful for small embedded-linux devices lacking the `tree` command!

Comment: this is nice, but misses the files in the current directory.

Comment: @JavaSheriff had provided a good one. This is the same with better look: `find . | sed -e "s/[^─][^\/]*\//   │/g" -e "s/│\([^ ]\)/├── \1/"`

Answer (score 92):

This command works to **display both folders and files**.

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
```

Example output:

```
.
 |-trace.pcap
 |-parent
 | |-chdir1
 | | |-file1.txt
 | |-chdir2
 | | |-file2.txt
 | | |-file3.sh
 |-tmp
 | |-json-c-0.11-4.el7_0.x86_64.rpm
```

*Source:* Comment from @javasheriff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree#comment89203646_3455651). Its submerged as a comment and posting it as answer helps users spot it easily.

Comment: for python3 I found `find .  |grep -vE 'pyc|swp|__init' | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"` working well

Comment: This was a great help as we didn't have tree installed on a certain server. This will most likely work on any standard Linux system.

Comment: Thanks. How can we make the results in alphabetical order?

Comment: @lavlex you can order the top-level directories with `find * | sed ...` but that's as far as I'm willing to think at the moment.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get the number of files in every directory as well?

Answer (score 51):

Since it was a successful comment, I am adding it as an answer:
To print the directory structure in the form of a tree,
**WITH FILES**

```
 find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
```

Comment: If you would like to sort your result list then combine the nice solution above with `sort` this way: `find . | sort | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/" `

Answer (score 25):

Since I was not too happy with the output of other (non-`tree`) answers (see [my comment at Hassou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree#comment114421253_3455651)), I tried to mimic `tree`s output a bit more.

It's similar to the answer of Robert but the horizontal lines do not all start at the beginning, but where there are supposed to start. Had to use `perl` though, but in my case, on the system where I don't have `tree`, `perl` is available.

```
ls -aR | grep ":$" | perl -pe 's/:$//;s/[^-][^\/]*\//    /g;s/^    (\S)/└── \1/;s/(^    |    (?= ))/│   /g;s/    (\S)/└── \1/'
```

Output (shortened):

```
.
└── fd
└── net
│   └── dev_snmp6
│   └── nfsfs
│   └── rpc
│   │   └── auth.unix.ip
│   └── stat
│   └── vlan
└── ns
└── task
│   └── 1310
│   │   └── net
│   │   │   └── dev_snmp6
│   │   │   └── rpc
│   │   │   │   └── auth.unix.gid
│   │   │   │   └── auth.unix.ip
│   │   │   └── stat
│   │   │   └── vlan
│   │   └── ns
```

Suggestions to avoid the superfluous vertical lines are welcome :-)

I still like [Ben's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree#comment28362526_3455651) in the comment of Hassou's answer very much, without the (not perfectly correct) lines it's much cleaner. For my use case I additionally removed the global indentation and added the option to also `ls` hidden files, like so:

```
ls -aR | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//  /g'
```

Output (shortened even more):

```
.
  fd
  net
    dev_snmp6
    nfsfs
    rpc
      auth.unix.ip
    stat
    vlan
  ns
```

Comment: The only way to get rid of the unwanted vertical lines when processing the output of `ls -R`  is to proceed from last to first line. See the awk-based solution I provided, which you could easily adapt to perl.

Answer (score 21):

To add Hassou's solution to your .bashrc, try:

```sh
alias lst='ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e '"'"'s/:$//'"'"' -e '"'"'s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'"'"' -e '"'"'s/^/   /'"'"' -e '"'"'s/-/|/'"'"
```

Comment: Beware of the newline character at the end of the first line if copying this directly

Comment: Nice alias. But there is missing ' ' (2 single quote chars) at the end. It works even without it, but... if you want to add some more commands at the end you will see the literal is not complete. So it should go 
```alias lst='ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e '"'"'s/:$//'"'"' -e '"'"'s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'"'"' -e '"'"'s/^/   /'"'"' -e '"'"'s/-/|/'"'"''```

Answer (score 12):

The best answer is, of course, `tree`. But, to improve on other answers that rely on grepping the output of `ls -R`, here is a shell script that uses awk to print a tree of subdirectories. First, an example of output:

```
.
└── matching
    ├── bib
    ├── data
    │   └── source
    │       └── html
    ├── data
    │   └── plots
    ├── method
    │   ├── info
    │   └── soft
    │       ├── imgs
    │       │   ├── ascii
    │       │   └── symbol
    │       └── js
    └── ms
```

Then, the code:

```
ls -qLR 2>/dev/null \
| grep '^./' \
| sed -e 's,:$,,' \
| awk '
    function tip(new) { stem = substr(stem, 1, length(stem) - 4) new }
    {
        path[NR] = $0
    }
    END {
        elbow = "└── "; pipe = "│   "; tee = "├── "; blank = "    "
        none = ""
        #
        # Model each stem on the previous one, going bottom up.
        for (row = NR; row > 0; row--) {
            #
            # gsub: count (and clean) all slash-ending components; hence,
            # reduce path to its last component.
            growth = gsub(/[^/]+\//, "", path[row]) - slashes
            if (growth == 0) {
                tip(tee)
            }
            else if (growth > 0) {
                if (stem) tip(pipe) # if...: stem is empty at first!
                for (d = 1; d < growth; d++) stem = stem blank
                stem = stem elbow
            }
            else {
                tip(none)
                below = substr(stem, length(stem) - 4, 4)
                if (below == blank) tip(elbow); else tip(tee)
            }
            path[row] = stem path[row]
            slashes += growth
        }
        root = "."; print root
        for (row = 1; row <= NR; row++) print path[row]
    }
'
```

The code gives better-looking results than other solutions because in a tree of subdirectories, the decorations in any branch depend on the branches below it. Hence, we need to process the output of `ls -R` in reverse order, from the last line to the first.

Comment: What system did you test it on? I get an error `awk: nonterminated character class [^` on gsub line on Mac.

Comment: @Andrei I tested it on Arch, where awk is symlinked to gawk (= GNU awk). So this may be another pesky awk/gawk difference. Perhaps you should escape the slash inside the character class: /[^\/]+\//

Answer (score 8):

I'm prettifying the output of @Hassou's answer with:

```sh
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//──/g' -e 's/─/├/' -e '$s/├/└/'
```

This is much like the output of `tree` now:

```
.
├─pkcs11
├─pki
├───ca-trust
├─────extracted
├───────java
├───────openssl
├───────pem
├─────source
├───────anchors
├─profile.d
└─ssh
```

You can also make an alias of it:

```sh
alias ltree=$'ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e \'s/:$//\' -e \'s/[^-][^\/]*\//──/g\' -e \'s/─/├/\' -e \'$s/├/└/\''
```

BTW, `tree` is not available in some environment, like MinGW. So the alternate is helpful.

Comment: gitbash on windows does not like the last expression, it says that it is not terminated

Comment: @LeosLiterak: On Windows, native `tree` should be available with Command Prompt (`cmd`) or PowerShell though :-)

Answer (score 5):

Adding the below function in bashrc lets you run the command without any arguments which displays the current directory structure and when run with any path as argument, will display the directory structure of that path. This avoids the need to switch to a particular directory before running the command.

```
function tree() {
    find ${1:-.} | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
}
```

This works in gitbash too.

Source: Comment from @javasheriff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree#comment89203646_3455651)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the combination of find and awk commands to print the directory tree. For details, please refer to "[How to print a multilevel tree directory structure using the linux find and awk combined commands](https://www.linuxcommands.site/tech-topic/how-to/how-to-print-tree-directory-structure-in-linux/)"

```
find . -type d | awk -F'/' '{ 
depth=3;
offset=2;
str="|  ";
path="";
if(NF >= 2 && NF < depth + offset) {
    while(offset < NF) {
        path = path "|  ";
        offset ++;
    }
    print path "|-- "$NF;
}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining and extending existing answers into `t` shell function

```bash
t() {
  find -E "${1:-.}" -maxdepth "${2:-3}" \
    -not -regex ".*\/((.idea|.git|.venv|node_modules|venv)\/.*|.DS_Store)" \
  | sort | sed \
    -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// ├ /g" \
    -e "s/├ \//├ /g" \
    -e "s/├  ├/│  ├/g" \
    -e "s/├  ├/│  ├/g" \
    -e "s/├  │/│  │/g" \
    -e '$s/├/└/'
}
```

Works on Mac:

```
$ t
.
 ├ src
 │  ├ .idea
 │  ├ plugins
 │  │  ├ .flake8
 │  │  ├ .git
 │  │  ├ .github
 │  │  ├ .gitignore
 │  │  ├ .pre-commit-config.yaml
 │  │  ├ .python-version
 │  │  ├ Makefile
 │  │  ├ README.md
 │  │  ├ buildspecs
 │  │  ├ cicd
 │  │  ├ cicd.py
 │  │  ├ docker
 │  │  ├ packages
 │  │  ├ plugin_template
 │  │  ├ plugins
 │  │  ├ scripts
 │  │  └ venv


$ t . 2
.
 ├ src
 │  ├ .idea
 │  └ plugins


$ t src/plugins/ | more
 │  ├
 │  ├ .flake8
 │  ├ .git
 │  ├ .github
 │  │  ├ pull_request_template.md
 │  ├ .gitignore
 │  ├ .pre-commit-config.yaml
 │  ├ .python-version
 │  ├ Makefile
 │  ├ README.md
 │  ├ buildspecs
 │  │  ├ test-and-deploy.yml
 │  ├ cicd
:
```

`| more` can be put at the end of the function for convenience.

Comment: Nice solution to copy paste to your `.bashrc`. On Linux (Debian 11) omit the `-E` option passed to `find`.

Comment: this is a gem <3

Answer (score 0):

We can use below command

tree

This will return tree like structure.

If you want entire directory till the end subdirectory. You need to fire below command.

find . -type d

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on msa's perl version I've tossed in a bit of ANSI color coding output matching default ls --color choices.  I also added files back into the listing.  Wrapped in a bash function for use in ~/.bashrc and formatted with commentary, it now looks like this:

```
function tree() {
    find ${1:-.} | perl -pe '
        chomp();                        # Lose the line ending for file tests
        $f=$_;                          # Keep full path in $f for file tests
        if(-d $f)     { $c="\e[0;34m" } # Directories BLUE
        elsif (-l $f) { $c="\e[0;36m" } # Links CYAN
        elsif (-X $f) { $c="\e[0;32m" } # Executables GREEN
        else          { $c="\e[0m" }    # Else just RESET
        s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g;           # Get rid of ./our/leading/path to just "  |path"
        s/\|([^ ]+)/└──$c$1\e[0m/;      # Change |path to └──path and add $c coloring with reset
        if (-d $f) {                    # If directory add trailing / too
            s/$/\//
        };
        print("\n");                    # Because we chomp()ed the ending off at the start
        END { print("\n"); }'           # One last line ending to keep it clean
}
```

I prefer perl for these kinds of shenanigans because: Perl makes it easier to deal with the file tests and ANSI escape sequences than sed.  Love it or hate it Perl is base install for nearly every Unix style OS.  I love Python, but it's useless for "one liners" like this that I want to throw in my ~/.bashrc tools pile.  The tree command is great, but again it isn't often installed and I find it easier to carry a bunch of magic spells in my ~/.bashrc spell book when working across random systems.