# Directory tree structure in shell

Tags: shell, command

I want to print a directory tree structure using shell commands, can anyone help me with idea of how to do it? As I am a bit new.

PS: I can't use Sed and Octs

```
.
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
  |-- Lorem
  |-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
-- Lorem
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  [Mild teasing: _It's a bad idea to have multiple files in a single directory that only differ in the number of trailing blanks (or other invisible characters) at the end of the name.  I don't see how else you get so many `Lorem`'s into a single directory (unless you're using carriage return to overwrite the distinct prefixes, I suppose)._]  You should show what you've tried, or how you plan to go about getting the list of directory names, for example.

Comment: is this a unix/linux system? If so see if your system has `ptree`. Else look for `tree` option when you read `man ps`. (Best to include a tag on your question for the type of OS you are using). Good luck.

Comment: yes am searching for something like that, however i don't want to use a prevues written code such as trees, not i can use sed, i would like to get the steps and idea what can i use in order to create such tree

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive solution which is not the most efficient but native `bash` and easy to understand:

```
$ cat tree.sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

tree()
{
        if [ "$1" = '-d' ]; then
                _TREE_DIRSONLY=1
                shift
        fi
        _tree "${1-.}"
}

_tree()
{
        local indent="${indent}"
        local dir=${1%/}

        printf "%s|-- %s\n" "${indent}" "${dir##*/}"
        indent="${indent}  "
        for file in "$1"/*; do
                if [ -d "${file}" ]; then
                        _tree "${file}"
                        continue
                fi
                (( _TREE_DIRSONLY > 0 )) && continue
                printf "%s|-- %s\n" "${indent}" "${file##*/}"
        done
}

tree "$@"
```

.

```
$ ./tree.sh /proc/fs
|-- fs
  |-- cifs
    |-- cifsFYI
    |-- DebugData
    |-- LinuxExtensionsEnabled
    |-- LookupCacheEnabled
    |-- MultiuserMount
    |-- SecurityFlags
    |-- traceSMB
  |-- ext4
  |-- jbd2
  |-- nfsd
  |-- nfsfs
    |-- servers
    |-- volumes
  |-- xfs
    |-- stat
    |-- xqm
    |-- xqmstat

$ ./tree.sh -d /proc/fs
|-- fs
  |-- cifs
  |-- ext4
  |-- jbd2
  |-- nfsd
  |-- nfsfs
  |-- xfs
```

Comment: This can also be a handy addition to the .bashrc file with the following alias `alias lst="tree . | less"`