# Add external libraries to CMakeList.txt c++

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries

I have my external library as shown in this picture that I create the symbolic links after:

[image]

and the headers related to the library in other file:

[image]

I'm working with `ROS ubuntu` and I need to add these libraries to my package to `CmakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})

rosbuild_add_executable(kinectueye src/kinect_ueye.cpp)
```

So my question is how can I add these folders (I think the first one that I need to add I'm not sure) to my `CmakeList.txt` file so as I can use the classes and the methods in my program.

Comment: Screenshots 404

Comment: @Pachonk  it was just a screenshot of files in a folder.. I don't have it anymore

Comment: 404s are why I hate questions containing links.

Comment: @Mitja When I posted that question I was just created my account so I didn't have enough reputations to post an image in my question without a link. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about those limitations. To me, it makes no sense to allow new accounts to embed links but not include images. Both can be used for spam, and links even better..
Also, I can't take my downvote from this question anymore as it is now >2hrs old (and, tbh, the question is kind of bad w/o the links working), so take an upvote to another reasonable question of yours instead.

Comment: @Mitja that's okay! I've found the library again and I just edited my post.. thanks for pointing that out.. (@Pachonk)

Comment: @Ja_cpp next time use [`tree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455675/3079302) or [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455651/3079302).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I would start with upgrade of CMAKE version.

You can use [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:include_directories) for header location and [LINK_DIRECTORIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:link_directories) + [TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries) for libraries

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(your/header/dir)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(your/library/dir)
rosbuild_add_executable(kinectueye src/kinect_ueye.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(kinectueye lib1 lib2 lib2 ...)
```

note that `lib1` is expanded to `liblib1.so` (on Linux), so [use ln](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/2838364) to create appropriate links in case you do not have them

Comment: Like that

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(home/jros/roskinectueye/MIXEDVISION/include/MIXEDVISION)


LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/jros/roskinectueye/MIXEDVISION/lib64)


rosbuild_add_executable(kinectueye src/kinect_ueye.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(kinectueye libgsl.so.0.16.0 libgslcblas.so.0.0.0)

Comment: `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(kinectueye gsl gslcblas ...)`

Comment: I get this error:  Linking CXX executable ../bin/kinectueye
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHalf
and for all the libraries !

Comment: make sure you have symbolic links in your directory libgsl.so ->  libgsl.so.0.16.0, etc

Comment: Yes I have it, as shown in the first image that I post

Comment: No you do not, you need libname without "numbers" at the end

Comment: create symbolic links

Comment: I do ! the file become like shortcut .. is that symbolic link ?

Comment: unfortunately yes, I get Linking CXX executable ../bin/kinectueye
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas ..... and some others

Comment: Please run `make VERBOSE=1` and copy here the full link command for kinectueye.

Comment: I get that: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1 kinectueye`, in the folder where you have generated build system from cmake

Comment: Sorry, I will not download the file. Please post it here. Just a link line.

Comment: Thank you @Peter It works now... I changed my package from Rosbuild to  catkin. and concerning the library I change it to *.so.

Comment: What's "kinectueye"?