# including external libraries in cmakelists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using cmake to build an executable to run on an Intel Galileo board.

My question is how do I include the external mraa library in the build process.

[Mraa library](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa)

1. When I download the library from git (1) do I need to build it as described here

[Mraa compiling instructions](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/building.html)

2. What do I need to put in my CMakeLists.txt file to pick up the library?

This is what I have thus far in my CMakeLists.txt file but I believe it is incorrect.

```
### MRAA ###
add_subdirectory(mraa-master/src)
file(GLOB mraa_SRC
    "mraa-master/src/*.c"
)

include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mraa-master/include"  )
add_library( ${MRAA_LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED  ${mraa_SRC}  )
```

Thank you

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

MESSAGE( STATUS "Starting build process")

SET( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL "Debug")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Building in debug mode")
elseif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL "Release")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Building in release mode")
endif()

SET(PROJECT_NAME "TestProject")
SET(APPLICATION_NAME "TestApplication")
SET(SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY "SafeString")
SET(APPLICATION_LIBRARY "Applibrary")

PROJECT( ${PROJECT_NAME} )

MESSAGE( STATUS "PROJECT: " ${PROJECT_NAME} )


SET(WRSDK_PATH "$ENV{WINDRIVER_SDK_DIR}")
IF (WRSDK_PATH)
else()
SET(WRSDK_PATH /opt/windriver/wrlinux/5.0-intel-quark/)
endif()

SET(APPLIBRARY_NAME  ${APPLICATION_LIBRARY} )
SET(SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY_NAME ${SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY} )

### SAFE STRING ###
add_subdirectory(SafeStringStaticLibrary/safeclib) 
file(GLOB safestring_SRC
"SafeStringStaticLibrary/safeclib/*.c" 
)

include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SafeStringStaticLibrary /safeclib"  ) 
add_library( ${SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED  ${safestring_SRC}  ) 

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(mraa
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa.git
    GIT_TAG        v0.8.0
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND "" )


file(GLOB app_SRC
"classes/*.cpp"
"Logger.cpp"
"sqlite3.c"
"shell.c"
)

add_library( ${APPLIBRARY_NAME} SHARED ${app_SRC})
include_directories(  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"     "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SafeStringStaticLibrary/include" )

add_executable( ${APPLICATION_NAME} ${APPLICATION_NAME}.cpp

include_directories(  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"   "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SafeStringStaticLibrary/include"  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/classes")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(  ${APPLICATION_NAME}  ${APPLIBRARY_NAME} ${SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY_NAME} -lrt -lpthread -lgcov -ldl)
```

Comment: here is your solution check out here

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570916/add-external-libraries-to-cmakelist-txt-c

Comment: @riverrock: For build external library within your project, you can use [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html). If you are new in CMake and using of this function is not clear for you, I recommend you to build external library outside of your project, and link  with it using its full path. There are many resources which describes how to link with external library.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev , I built the mraa library outside of my project using the instructions provided here [link](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/building.html). Then I included these two lines in my CMakeLists.txt file. `include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mraa-master/include"  ) TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(  ${APPLICATION_NAME}  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mraa-master/build/src/libmraa.so)` . The error that I'm getting is **mraa-master/build/src/libmraa.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format**

Comment: If you crosscompile your project, then you should also crosscompile `mraa` library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the mraa library is a cmake-enabled library. How do I include it within my cmake enabled project so that it gets cross compiled with the rest of the code? Thanks

Comment: If you build `mraa` library outside of your project, just use same environment for build `mraa`. Probably, you need to additionally set `BUILDARCH` variable for `mraa` library build. Without knowing way, how you build yout project, it is difficult for give more concrete advice.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Could I use this code in my project's cmakelists.txt file? `include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(mraa
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa.git
        GIT_TAG        v0.8.0
)`

Comment: You may try. Unless your project has common options with `mraa` one, it should work. But it seems that you should set `BUILDARCH` in any case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've posted my cMakeLists.txt file for the project. You can see it creates an executable called "TestApplication" and a shared library called libApplibrary.so. You can see I build the safestring library and link it on the last line. I've brought in the mraa library using ExternalProject_Add() with no errors.  What should I include in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ) to link with the mraa library? Thanks

Comment: You should use full path to `mraa` library to build with it. Something like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mraa-prefix/src/mraa-build/src/libmraa.so`. My previous comment actually correct for the case, when you build `mraa` using `add_subdirectory(mraa)` way. command (previously you should downloaded mraa sources into `mraa` directory in source tree). In case of ExternalProject_Add I am unsure that `mraa` will be crosscompiled as main project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok thanks I will not use `ExternalProject_Add()`. Three more questions if you don't mind :) 1) what directory should I put in `add_subdirectory()` ? 2) Do I need to use `include_directories()` for the header files also? 3)  Should  `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( )` look like this?  `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(  ${APPLICATION_NAME}  ${APPLIBRARY_NAME} ${SAFE_STRING_LIBRARY_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mraa-prefix/src/mraa-build/src/libmraa.so -lrt -lpthread -lgcov -ldl)`

Comment: You deleted almost everything from your question, why did you do that? If you have accedentally pressed `Submit` button while edited, you can restore original content of the question from the history of edits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way for build your project alongside with 3d party project is `add_subdirectory()` that subproject. Approach below implies that you (manually) download(`git clone`) sources of `mraa` project into `mraa-lib` subdirectory of your project's sources.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

MESSAGE( STATUS "Starting build process")

# Configure subproject before definition of variables for main project.
#
# Subproject defines *mraa* library target.
add_subdirectory(mraa-lib)

# Before installation, public mraa headers are contained under *api* subdirectory.
include_directories(mraa-lib/api)

... # create executable ${APPLICATION_NAME}

# Linking with mraa library is straightforward.
target_link_libraries(${APPLICATION_NAME} mraa)
```

That way `mraa` subproject will be configured, built and installed alongside with your project. So, if you cross-compile your project(using toolchain file, or inside IDE), the subproject will also be cross-compiled.