# SHA-1 hashing by openSSL in android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, boringssl

I am creating an encryption library in android studio by android NDK. I am using CMakeLists.txt script.

In the C++ file, I want to include `#include <openssl/sha.h>`.

How can I include OpenSSL in my c++ file?

Comment: Also see [EVP Message Digests](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests) on the OpenSSL wiki. [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) offers some hints when using OpenSSL and C++.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have in `CMakeLists.txt` a line like

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM "/path/to/openssl")
```

then in the C++ source file you simply

```
#include <sha.h> // or #include <openssl/sha.h>
```

Comment: include_directories(src/main/cpp/openssl/).
It is giving `undefined reference to ...` for every function error.

Comment: @MAYANKJINDAL That's a linker error. Make sure you link the openssl library with your project. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570916/add-external-libraries-to-cmakelist-txt-c) for how to add target link library.