# CMake how to force third_party library include the project file in current project source directory?

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I have a pre-compiled dependency library `A` which has only `include/` and `lib/`

`A` was built with system library `B` which was installed in `/usr/local/include/B/` and `/usr/local/lib/B`

But on my building system doesn't have library `B` and do not allow me to modify the system (no privilege).

I downloaded `B` and put `B_include` in local project `C`'s `include` directory and `B_lib` in `C`'s `lib` directory.

I tried in `CMakeList.txt` of local project:

```sh
include_directories(
    C_INCLUDE_DIR
    B_INCLUDE_DIR
)

link_directories(
    C_LIB_DIR
    B_LIB_DIR
)
```

But when compile `C` against library `A`, `A`'s include can not find the local header file `B_INCLUDE_DIR`. Does anyone know how to force CMake to find the local library file other than directly navigate into system `include` and `lib` directories?

To sum up, can I tell CMake to force a pre-compiled library to use local `include` file?

Comment: "*But it doesn't work*"... This is a pretty vague problem description. Could you please describe *how* it doesn't work, including any relevant error messages or undesired behaviors. Also, it looks like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24570916/3987854) addresses something very similar to what you're asking. Specifically, `link_directories()` doesn't actually link the libraries, it only provides an additional path to the linker for library searching.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. It turn out to be my own mistake. Thanks to [squareskittles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854/squareskittles)'s comments.

the following CMakeList commends will do the work nicely:

```sh
include_directories(
    C_INCLUDE_DIR
    B_INCLUDE_DIR
)

link_directories(
    C_LIB_DIR
    B_LIB_DIR
)

rosbuild_add_executable(your_executable src/your_source_file.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(your_executable lib1.so lib2.so lib3.so ...)
```