# Unix command to print directory structure in the form of a tree?

Tags: unix

I am a newbie to `UNIX`, i want to print tree structure of files in a directory. below image is example in `DOS`, what will be the command of Unix to achieve same objective

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command to print directory structure in the form of a tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree)

Comment: @sinclair Linux command won't work for Unix

Comment: It's called `tree` as well: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Comment: @miku its not working on my UNIX Machine, if you have please try once and let me know

Comment: Personally, I'd use `find | sort`. `tree` rarely works for me as the directories quickly exceed the width of the prompt on Windows. If you really wanted, I'm sure there's a way to do this by piping the `sort` output to `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "tree" command.  If you are having issues running it you might have to find out how to install it on your specific distribution.  For ubuntu installs you can find instructions here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/507588/not-able-to-install-tree-comand-in-ubuntu

Not sure what you mean by "on Unix".  What OS are you running, specifically?  Tree should be compatible on Unix systems.  You may just have to compile it for your particular OS.

This command prints output like the following (on cygwin):

[image]