# How include file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have `index.php` file in directory `My`.

This file has including of file `core/coreEngine.php`

Inside `coreEngine.php` I try include another file `config/test.php` that is located on the previous directory:

```
index.php
/core/coreEngine.php
/config/test.php
```

I tried all cases:

```
require_once '../config/test.php';
require_once '../../config/test.php';
require_once '.../config/test.php';
```

Comment: [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Comment: Your directory structure is unclear to me, could you please [provide a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3455675/4233593)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
My/index.php
My/core/coreEngine.php <--- you are here
My/config/test.php     <--- you want to go here
```

You want to go back to My directory, so 2 directories back :

```
require_once '../../config/test.php';
```

BUT I strongly recommend to use absolute path instead of the relative one. You might want to use something like :

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/test.php');
```