# Passing parameters to a print directory like tree command

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing, alias, zsh

Following an answer from [Linux command to print directory structure in the form of a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree)

I've got:

`ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

To list a tree directory.

**Instead of just creating an alias I want it to behave like a normal command and accept parameters.**

I have this directory structure:

```
   |-myhome
   |---top
   |-----test
   |-------folder1
   |-------folder2
   |-------folder3
```

if I want this (from "top"):

```
   |-test
   |---folder1
   |---folder2
   |---folder3
```

I have to `cd top` an then `ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

or, from "myhome": `ls -R top | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

I want something along the lines of:

`lstree <dir>`

in this case (from "top"):

`lstree test`

which I don't get from an **alias**

I'm looking into bash functions:

```sh
function ls4less(){ ls -R $1 | less}
```

which then I could invoke from "top"

```sh
ls4less
```

yielding

```
test

./test:
folder1
folder2
folder3

./test/folder1:
file11.txt
file12.txt

./test/folder2:
file21.txt
file22.txt

./test/folder3:
file31.txt
file32.txt
file33.txt
(END)
```

or

```sh
ls4less test
```

yielding

```
folder1
folder2
folder3

test/folder1:
file11.txt
file12.txt

test/folder2:
file21.txt
file22.txt

test/folder3:
file31.txt
file32.txt
file33.txt
(END)
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this as _zsh_ too, when you are explicitly asking for a _bash_ solution?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score -1):

I've got two versions:

```
function lstree_1(){ls -R "$1" | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'}
```

```
function lstree_2(){echo "$1" | ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'}
```

Enjoy

Comment: Good answer, but please remember to enclose `$1` with double quotes.