# Equivalent to 'Tree' command but not recursive?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for an alternative to 'Tree' command in Linux however I want it to be based on NOT a recursive algorithm.

Tree command is based on a recursive algorithm, as seen from its description:

```
Tree is a recursive directory listing program that produces a depth indented listing of files.
```

Is there another way which is not recursive?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's `ls` in Unix, `dir` in DOS.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your reply. However, 'ls' is not equivalent to Tree. I'm looking for a command to write the whole tree. 'ls' prints out only content of the currenty directory.

Comment: Writing the whole directory tree, regardless of depth, is an inherently recursive operation.  What do you think would be the point of a non-recursive implementation?

Comment: If you want to print out the whole tree almost every command out there in linux does use end up using recursion. e.g. `ls` has a -R option and the documentation of that option implies recursive algorithm. Most real life implementations will likely be recursive. 
You might want to look at this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree

Comment: The term "recursive" in the description of the `tree` command does not necessarily say that the implementation uses recursion (although this is probably the case). It only means that it will descend into all directories, similar to the `-r` or `-R` option of several commands. If you want to discuss the implementation you should show the implementation in your question.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand the purpose of the -R option, since it traverses the filesystem recursively by default, without this option, and -RL 1 doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

With `tree -L <level>` you can specify how many level directories deep to descend. In your case it would be:

> tree -L 1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what I'm looking for, I want to get the exact same output as 'Tree' command, including all levels, however I want the implementation to be NOT recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the -d flag which only shows the directory tree (with no files).
From the [tree man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree):

> -d
>
> List directories only.

```
tree -d /path/to/dir
```