# Colored Text in Git Bash Output

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I made an alias to print the current directory tree:

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"

.
 |-trace.pcap
 |-parent
 | |-chdir1
 | | |-file1.txt
 | |-chdir2
 | | |-file2.txt
 | | |-file3.sh
 |-tmp
 | |-json-c-0.11-4.el7_0.x86_64.rpm
```

Which works fine, however it is hard to interpret a wall of white text. I was wondering how I could make folder names and file names different colors?

I can't use the "tree" command, everything will need to be done manually with nothing 3rd party.

Comment: If you want readability, so why not `ls -R`? `"s/[^-][^\/]*\//` What is going on here? Why do you replace these characters?

Comment: I'm just using what I found in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree

Answer (score 3):

You could print it with `printf` with color codes:

```
find . '(' \
     '(' -type d -printf "\033[31m" ')' -o \
     '(' -type f -printf "\033[32m" ')' -o \
                 -printf "\033[33m" \
      ')' -printf "%f""\033[39m""\n"
```

Comment: How do I fit this within my tree output formatting?

Comment: `How do I fit this within my tree output formatting?` You modify `find` with `%p` and then modify your `sed` script to take color codes into account. You can learn sed from https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and find has semi-good reference at [man find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Why not `"%f\033[39m\n"`

Comment: Cosmetics, I like to visually separate color codes from the rest of the string, so it's visible.