# How to cd to a random path?

Tags: bash, random

I want to generate a random existing path to `cd` and write file in it, if possible random from a specified root (the point is that can be used like `cd /home/foobar/$RANDOM`).

I think I can do this by listing all paths with ls and awk with this command, according to [ls command: how can I get a recursive full-path listing, one line per file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file)

```
ls -R /path | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }'
```

And giving result line per line to `$(dirname "${LINE_FILE}")` and finishing by purging dupes.

It should work but I need generate a lot of random existing paths and I hope a quicker solution exist (this generation may take a lot of time, worky but dirty). Any better ideas?

Comment: "worky but dirty" is my new favourite phrase

Comment: It's like Crusader Kings II, sometimes the worst way might be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variant with `find` + `sort -R`:

```
startDir='/your/path'
maxPathRange=10
endPath=$startDir

for (( i=1; i<=$((1 + RANDOM % $maxPathRange)); i++ )); do
    directory=$(find "$endPath" -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path "$endPath" -printf "%f\n" | sort -R | head -n 1) 
    if [[ -z $directory ]]; then break; fi
    endPath=$endPath/$directory
done <<< "$directory"

cd "$endPath" && pwd
```

Comment: That's a massive [useless use of `echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) you have there.  If the value of `$directory` contains something which `echo -e` will interpret as an escape code, it will result in the wrong string; and anyway, the purpose of `<<<` is so you can say simply `<<<"$directory"`.

Comment: I edited to remove the remaining `echo` in command substitutions as well.  It's an anti-idiom which exacerbates any quoting issues, and you had several.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too proficient in bash, so I won't give you a straight coded answer, but here's how you can achieve it.

From what I understand you are using 1 `ls` command to list the whole file system.

That will take a long time. Instead, use `ls` to list only folders in the current directory, pick a random one and then do the same to the one you picked.

This could go on until you get to a folder with no folders inside it.

If you want to have the possibility of picking a folder which does contain other folders and stop there, include in your random picking, an option that will not pick any file and stop in current directory. This option should have a small probability of occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt.

```
randomcd () {
    local p=$(printf '%s\n' . */ | sort -R | head -n 1)
    case $p in '.' | '*/') pwd; return;; esac
    ( cd "$p"; randomcd )
}
```

Unfortunately `sort -R` is not entirely portable.  If you don't have `shuf` either, something like this might work:

```
shuffle () {
    perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>'
}
```

Comment: You can remove `.` from the `printf` argument list if you want to always `cd` to a leaf directory, but then it's even less properly random.