# ls command: how can I get a recursive full-path listing, one line per file, filtering by permissions?

Tags: awk, grep, ls, mapr

My goal is to be able to identify all of the paths to Streams (files) within a MapR cluster filesystem.

Working through the problem I've identified that within a MapR cluster, Streams are stored as links to MapR Tables with read-only permissions.

These can easily be discovered using:

```
ls -alR -1 /mapr |grep 'lr-------- 1 mapr mapr'

lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jan 24 13:02 f -> mapr::table::2129.42.131292
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jan 27 12:49 transactions -> mapr::table::2129.48.393912
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jan  3 12:52 customers -> mapr::table::2129.36.131280
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jan  3 16:47 creditcards -> mapr::table::2129.39.131286
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jan  3 12:40 databroker -> mapr::table::2129.33.131274
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 May 25 13:00 drill_test -> mapr::table::2049.12355.3399972
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jun 14 05:23 geo -> mapr::table::2049.22145.4864546
lr-------- 1 mapr mapr 2 Jun  7 10:36 bonus -> mapr::table::2049.26487.4074656
```

Two problems remain:

The output displayed is both Stream files AND MapR-DB Tables; further identification could be performed using maprcli commands, but in order to do this I need the full path in order to pipe the files into another program...

Obtaining the paths is easily performed using the solution here: [ls command: how can I get a recursive full-path listing, one line per file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file)

But then the identification mask in the *grep* command can't be applied to shortlist, and I'm left with a list of *all* the files in the cluster.

One approach I thought might work was to extract the specific file links in question using:

```
ls -alR -1 /mapr |grep 'lr-------- 1 mapr mapr' |awk '{ print $9 }'
```

which results in:

```
f
transactions
customers
creditcards
databroker
drill_test
geo
bonus
```

and then pipe them into a *find* loop (or something"?), but this performs poorly.

Does anyone have an approach that outputs the path and filename recursively **alongside permissions** allowing for filtering like demonstrated in the GREP command?  The (what I consider safe) assumption I'm making is that within the cluster, only MapR-DB Tables and MapR Streams will have these permissions, and from a data management perspective, identifying both will provide benefit as services appear within a cluster that start writing data we haven't yet captured in downstream systems (reporting, ETL, etc).

Better yet, the magic bullet is generating a list of MapR Streams registered in the cluster some other (more reliable) way. ;)

Comment: do you know about `find . -ls` ? `man find` will reveal other options to help your filter and focus your search. Then you can search here for `[linux] [find] optInQuestion`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  This helps a lot!