# How to get a comma separated list of files of all subfolders which are found automatically?

Tags: find, zsh, ls

I want a list of all files which are in various subfolders.
Since subfolders are constantly added I need to update the list of subfolders automatically.

For the example I have added the subfolders `html,pdf,md`.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# I get all the subfolders of the folder DIR automatically as a list.
folder=$(ls -l DIR/ | awk '/^d/ { print $9 }' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' )
echo "Folder: $folder"
# --> html,md,pdf

# Now get the files of the found subfolders
files=$(ls -m DIR/{$folder}/*)
echo "Files: $files"
# DOES NOT WORK

# this works instead:
ls -m DIR/{html,md,pdf}/*
```

Putting in the subfolder’s names manually in the `ls`-command works fine.

The output I am hoping to get back from `$files` is (example):

```
DIR/html/dataStorage.html, DIR/md/dataStorage.md, DIR/pdf/data.pdf, DIR/pdf/dataStorage.pdf
```

I am using `zsh`.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @LukasCB : Note that you get the list of all subfolders of `DIR` by `DIR/*/(D)`. Try for instance `echo DIR/*/(D)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. All files in all subfolders are automatically found. No need to check for subfolders first.

```
files=$(ls -R DIR | awk '
  /:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
  /:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
  NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' )
```

It is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767559/8584652 and slightly modified (piping to `tr` and using `sed` in the end).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a comma-separated list (which wouldn't be of much use if an element can contain a comma) when you have proper arrays.

Using brace expansion to create three separate globs to expand

```
files=(DIR/*/*.{html,md,pdf})
```

or using the `KSHGLOB` option to create one glob

```
setopt KSHGLOB
files=(DIR/*/*.@(html|md|pdf))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it takes into account that I *already know* the name of the subfolders. I was interested in getting the files of the subfolders which I do not know (and want to type in manually).

Comment: Nothing here assumes the names of the subfolders. `DIR/*/` matches the subfolders; `DIR/*/*.html`, e.g., matches the files with the `.html` extension in each of those subfolders.