# How can I shuffle the lines of a text file on the Unix command line or in a shell script?

Tags: shell, random, command-line, awk, shuffle

I want to shuffle the lines of a text file randomly and create a new file. The file may have several thousands of lines.

How can I do that with `cat`, `awk`, `cut`, etc?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886237/how-can-i-randomize-the-lines-in-a-file-using-a-standard-tools-on-redhat-linux

Comment: Yep, there are some other nice answers in that original question as well.

Comment: so, were you making a wpa wordlist?
(just a random guess)

Answer (score 420, accepted):

You can use [`shuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf). On some systems at least (doesn't appear to be in POSIX).

As jleedev pointed out: `sort -R` might also be an option. On some systems at least; well, you get the picture. [It has been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line/2153897#comment16274986_2153897) that `sort -R` doesn't really shuffle but instead sort items according to their hash value.

<sup>[Editor's note: `sort -R` *almost* shuffles, except that *duplicate* lines / sort keys always end up *next to each other*. In other words: only with *unique* input lines / keys is it a true shuffle. While it's true that the output order is determined by *hash values*, the randomness comes from choosing a random hash *function* - see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html).]</sup>

Comment: Cool, I hadn't known about shuf. It looks like it's part of coreutils but the version I have installed on my server doesn't have shuf.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be GNU-only stuff, unfortunately. Nothing of it in POSIX.

Comment: It's odd that GNU coreutils has both `shuf` and `sort -R`.

Comment: Note that shuf is probably a more proper version of what you're trying to do.  Read this article on why shuffling naively can be a bad idea: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html

Comment: conradlee: Both `sort -R` and `shuf` should do a reasonably well shuffle. If not, well, then the authors were morons. Nowhere I said anything of shuffling naïvely.

Comment: `shuf` and `sort -R` differ slightly, because `sort -R` randomly orders the elements according to **hash** of them, which is, `sort -R` will put the repeated elements together, while `shuf` shuffles all the elements randomly.

Comment: +1 for `shuf` -- It ran much faster in my case (shuffling 60gb file took  maybe 20 minutes with `shuf` vs. `sort -R` was running for 1.5+ hours before I killed it)

Comment: The `rl` command is also available from the `randomize-lines` package, at least on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Richard: The author recommends using `shuf`.

Comment: For OS X users: `brew install coreutils`, then use `gshuf ...` (:

Comment: `sort -R` and `shuf` should be seen as completely different. `sort -R` is deterministic. If you call it twice at different times on the same input you will get the same answer. `shuf`, on the other hand, produces randomized output, so it will most likely give different output on the same input.

Comment: That is not correct. "sort -R" uses a *different* random hash key each time you invoke it, so it produces different output each time.

Comment: FreeBSD has `sysutils/coreutils` in the Ports/pkg. Use `gshuf`. FYI.

Comment: To clarify the `sort -R` issue: the results are randomly ordered _in general_, _except_ for _duplicate lines_ (keys), which always end up next to each other. The reason is that sorting is based on _hashes_ of the input lines (keys) generated by a _randomly chosen hash function_.

Comment: Note on randomness: per the GNU docs, "By default these commands use an internal pseudo-random generator initialized by a small amount of entropy, but can be directed to use an external source with the --random-source=file option."

Comment: I assume `sort -R` would be slower than `shuf` since sorting is an `O(n logn)` operation, and shuffeling is `O(n)`?

Comment: @ThomasAhle That would be assuming both programs are optimal (or equally suboptimal)… but `shuf` is indeed about 10x faster than `sort -R` for 100,000 short lines in my tests. (As an aside, `shuf -n `<num> does not offer noticeable performance improvements over `shuf | head -n `<num>, suggesting it is not handled optimally.)

Answer (score 93):

Perl one-liner would be a simple version of Maxim's solution

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);' < myfile
```

Comment: This was the only script on this page that returned REAL random lines. Other awk solutions often printed duplicate output.

Comment: But be careful because in the out you will lost one line :) It just will be joined with another line :)

Comment: @JavaRunner: I assume you're talking about input without a trailing `\n`; yes, that `\n` must be present - and it typically _is_  - otherwise you'll get what you describe.

Comment: Wonderfully concise. I suggest replacing `<STDIN>` with `<>`, so the solution works with input from _files_ too.

Comment: The other answers suggest utilities that you may or may not already have on your system. Everyone has perl, though (and if you don't, then something you need will require it at some point).

Answer (score 68):

This answer complements the many great existing answers in the following ways:

- The existing answers are **packaged into flexible *shell functions***:

  - The functions **take not only `stdin` input, but alternatively also *filename* arguments**
  - The functions **take extra steps to handle `SIGPIPE` in the usual way** (quiet termination with exit code `141`), as opposed to breaking noisily. This is important when piping the function output to a pipe that is closed early, such as when piping to `head`.
- A **performance comparison** is made.

---

- **POSIX-compliant** function based on **`awk`, `sort`, and `cut`**, adapted from the [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153889/45375):

```sh
shuf() { awk 'BEGIN {srand(); OFMT="%.17f"} {print rand(), $0}' "$@" |
               sort -k1,1n | cut -d ' ' -f2-; }
```

- **Perl**-based function - adapted from [Moonyoung Kang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511327/45375):

```sh
shuf() { perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<>);' "$@"; }
```

- **Python**-based function, adapted from [scai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17587496/45375):

```sh
shuf() { python -c '
import sys, random, fileinput; from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL;    
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL); lines=[line for line in fileinput.input()];   
random.shuffle(lines); sys.stdout.write("".join(lines))
' "$@"; }
```

<sup>See the bottom section for a *Windows* version of this function.</sup>

- **Ruby**-based function, adapted from [hoffmanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27509631/45375):

```sh
shuf() { ruby -e 'Signal.trap("SIGPIPE", "SYSTEM_DEFAULT");
                     puts ARGF.readlines.shuffle' "$@"; }
```

---

**Performance comparison:**

Note: These numbers were obtained on a late-2012 iMac with 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 and a Fusion Drive, running OSX 10.10.3. **While timings will vary with OS used, machine specs, `awk` implementation used** (e.g., the BSD `awk` version used on OSX is usually slower than GNU `awk` and especially `mawk`), **this should provide a general sense of *relative* performance**.

**Input** file is a **1-million-lines file** produced with `seq -f 'line %.0f' 1000000`.
Times are listed in ascending order (fastest first):

- **`shuf`**

  - `0.090s`
- **Ruby** 2.0.0

  - `0.289s`
- **Perl** 5.18.2

  - `0.589s`
- **Python**

  - `1.342s` with Python 2.7.6; `2.407s`(!) with Python 3.4.2
- **`awk` + `sort` + `cut`**

  - `3.003s` with BSD `awk`; `2.388s` with GNU `awk` (4.1.1); `1.811s` with `mawk` (1.3.4);

For further comparison, the solutions not packaged as functions above:

- **`sort -R`** (not a true shuffle if there are duplicate input lines)

  - `10.661s` - allocating more memory doesn't seem to make a difference
- **Scala**

  - `24.229s`
- **`bash` loops + `sort`**

  - `32.593s`

**Conclusions**:

- **Use `shuf`, if you can** - it's the fastest by far.
- **Ruby** does well, followed by **Perl**.
- **Python** is noticeably slower than Ruby and Perl, and, comparing Python versions, 2.7.6 is quite a bit faster than 3.4.1
- **Use the POSIX-compliant `awk` + `sort` + `cut` combo as a last resort**; which `awk` implementation you use matters (`mawk` is faster than GNU `awk`, BSD `awk` is slowest).
- Stay away from `sort -R`, `bash` loops, and Scala.

---

***Windows* versions of the *Python* solution** (the Python code is identical, except for variations in quoting and the removal of the signal-related statements, which aren't supported on Windows):

- For PowerShell (in Windows PowerShell, you'll have to adjust `$OutputEncoding` if you want to send non-ASCII characters via the pipeline):

```bsh
# Call as `shuf someFile.txt` or `Get-Content someFile.txt | shuf`
function shuf {
  $Input | python -c @'
import sys, random, fileinput;
lines=[line for line in fileinput.input()];
random.shuffle(lines); sys.stdout.write(''.join(lines))
'@ $args  
}
```

Note that PowerShell can natively shuffle via its `Get-Random` cmdlet (though performance may be a problem); e.g.:
`Get-Content someFile.txt | Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)`

- For `cmd.exe` (a batch file):

Save to file `shuf.cmd`, for instance:

```
@echo off
python -c "import sys, random, fileinput; lines=[line for line in fileinput.input()]; random.shuffle(lines); sys.stdout.write(''.join(lines))" %*
```

Comment: SIGPIPE doesn't exist on Windows so I used this simple one-liner instead: `python -c "import sys, random; lines = [x for x in sys.stdin.read().splitlines()] ; random.shuffle(lines); print(\"\n\".join([line for line in lines]));"`

Comment: @elig: Thanks, but omitting `from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL; signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL);` from the original solution is sufficient, and retains the flexibility of also being able to pass filename _arguments_ - no need to change anything else (except for quoting) - please see the new section I've added at the bottom.

Answer (score 27):

I use a tiny perl script, which I call "unsort":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use List::Util 'shuffle';
@list = <STDIN>;
print shuffle(@list);
```

I've also got a NULL-delimited version, called "unsort0" ... handy for use with find -print0 and so on.

PS:  Voted up 'shuf' too, I had no idea that was there in coreutils these days ... the above may still be useful if your systems doesn't have 'shuf'.

Comment: nice one, RHEL 5.6 does not have shuf (

Comment: Nicely done;  I suggest replacing `<STDIN>` with `<>` in order to make the solution work with input from _files_ too.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a first try that's easy on the coder but hard on the CPU which prepends a random number to each line, sorts them and then strips the random number from each line. In effect, the lines are sorted randomly:

```
cat myfile | awk 'BEGIN{srand();}{print rand()"\t"$0}' | sort -k1 -n | cut -f2- > myfile.shuffled
```

Comment: UUOC. pass the file to awk itself.

Comment: Right, I debug with `head myfile | awk ...`. Then I just change it to cat; that's why it was left there.

Comment: Don't need `-k1 -n` for sort, since the output of awk's `rand()` is a decimal between 0 and 1 and because all that matters is that it gets reordered somehow. `-k1` might help speed it up by ignoring the rest of the line, though the output of rand() should be unique enough to short-circuit the comparison.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Most so called useless uses of cat are actually useful for being consistent between piped commands and not. Better to keep the `cat filename |` (or `< filename |`) than remember how each single program takes file input (or not).

Comment: shuf() { awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand()"\t"$0}' "$@" | sort | cut -f2- ;}

Comment: @bonsaiviking: `-k1` is redundant, because it still sorts the line _as a whole_, because no _stop_ field is specified; to truly limit sorting to the first field, `-k1,1` is needed. However, using `-n`  speeds up sorting noticeably.
Thus, you should use `-k1,1 -n` (to be explicit) or, taking advantage of the fact that the sort key is the first field and that  `sort` uses longest-prefix matching when detecting numbers, just `-n`.

Answer (score 16):

here's an awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand() }
{ lines[++d]=$0 }
END{
    while (1){
    if (e==d) {break}
        RANDOM = int(1 + rand() * d)
        if ( RANDOM in lines  ){
            print lines[RANDOM]
            delete lines[RANDOM]
            ++e
        }
    }
}' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ ./shell.sh
7
5
10
9
6
8
2
1
3
4
```

Comment: Nicely done, but in practice much slower than [the OP's own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153889/45375), which combines `awk` with `sort` and `cut`. For no more than several thousands line it doesn't make much of a difference, but with higher line counts it matters (the threshold depends on the `awk` implementation used). A slight simplification would be to replace lines `while (1){` and `if (e==d) {break}` with `while (e<d)`.

Answer (score 11):

A one-liner for python:

```
python -c "import random, sys; lines = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines(); random.shuffle(lines); print ''.join(lines)," myFile
```

And for printing just a single random line:

```
python -c "import random, sys; print random.choice(open(sys.argv[1]).readlines())," myFile
```

But see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062966/1340631) for the drawbacks of python's `random.shuffle()`. It won't work well with many (more than 2080) elements.

Comment: the "drawback" is not specific to Python. Finite PRNG periods could be workarounded by reseeding PRNG with entropy from the system like `/dev/urandom` does. To utilize it from Python: `random.SystemRandom().shuffle(L)`.

Comment: doesn't the join() need to be on '\n' so the lines get printed each in its own ?

Comment: @elig: No, because `.readLines()` returns the lines _with_ a trailing newline.

Answer (score 9):

Simple awk-based function will do the job:

```
shuffle() { 
    awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}' | sort -n | cut -c8-
}
```

usage:

```
any_command | shuffle
```

This should work on almost any UNIX. Tested on Linux, Solaris and HP-UX.

**Update:**

Note, that leading zeros (`%06d`) and `rand()` multiplication makes it to work properly also on systems where `sort` does not understand numbers. It can be sorted via lexicographical order (a.k.a. normal string compare).

Comment: Good idea to package the OP's own answer as a function; if you append `"$@"`, it'll also work with _files_ as input. There is no reason to multiply `rand()`, because `sort -n` is capable of sorting decimal fractions. It is, however, a good idea to control `awk`'s output format, because with the default format, `%.6g`, `rand()` will output the occasional number in _exponential_ notation.
While shuffling up to 1 million lines is arguably enough in practice, it's easy to support more lines without paying much of a performance penalty; e.g. `%.17f`.

Comment: @mklement0 I didn't notice OPs answer while writing mine. rand() is multiplied by 10e6 to make it work with solaris or hpux sort as far as I remember. Good idea with "$@"

Comment: Got it, thanks; perhaps you could add this rationale for the multiplication to the answer itself; generally, according to POSIX, [`sort` should be able to handle decimal fractions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) (even with thousands separators, as I've just noticed).

Answer (score 8):

Ruby FTW:

```
ls | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.readlines.shuffle'
```

Comment: Great stuff; If you use `puts ARGF.readlines.shuffle`, you can make it work with both stdin input and filename arguments.

Comment: Even shorter `ruby -e 'puts $<.sort_by{rand}'` — ARGF is already an enumerable, so we can shuffle the lines by sorting it by random values.

Answer (score 8):

A simple and intuitive way would be to use **[`shuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html)**.

**Example:**

Assume `words.txt` as:

```
the
an
linux
ubuntu
life
good
breeze
```

To shuffle the lines, do:

```
$ shuf words.txt
```

which would throws the shuffled lines to *standard output*; So, you've to *pipe* it to an *output file* like:

```
$ shuf words.txt > shuffled_words.txt
```

One such *shuffle run* could yield:

```
breeze
the
linux
an
ubuntu
good
life
```

Answer (score 6):

One liner for Python based on [scai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17587496/34935), but a) takes stdin, b) makes the result repeatable with seed, c) picks out only 200 of all lines.

```
$ cat file | python -c "import random, sys; 
  random.seed(100); print ''.join(random.sample(sys.stdin.readlines(), 200))," \
  > 200lines.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

We have a package to do the very job:

```
sudo apt-get install randomize-lines
```

**Example:**

Create an ordered list of numbers, and save it to 1000.txt:

```
seq 1000 > 1000.txt
```

to shuffle it, simply use

```
rl 1000.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If like me you came here to look for an alternate to `shuf` for macOS then use `randomize-lines`.

Install `randomize-lines`(homebrew) package, which has an `rl` command which has similar functionality to `shuf`.

`brew install randomize-lines`

```
Usage: rl [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Randomize the lines of a file (or stdin).

  -c, --count=N  select N lines from the file
  -r, --reselect lines may be selected multiple times
  -o, --output=FILE
                 send output to file
  -d, --delimiter=DELIM
                 specify line delimiter (one character)
  -0, --null     set line delimiter to null character
                 (useful with find -print0)
  -n, --line-number
                 print line number with output lines
  -q, --quiet, --silent
                 do not output any errors or warnings
  -h, --help     display this help and exit
  -V, --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: Installing Coreutils with `brew install coreutils` provides the `shuf` binary as `gshuf`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a python script that I saved as rand.py in my home folder:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    flist = f.readlines()
    random.shuffle(flist)

    for line in flist:
      print line.strip()
```

On Mac OSX `sort -R` and `shuf` are not available so you can alias this in your bash_profile as:

```
alias shuf='python rand.py'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Scala installed, here's a one-liner to shuffle the input:

```
ls -1 | scala -e 'for (l <- util.Random.shuffle(io.Source.stdin.getLines.toList)) println(l)'
```

Comment: Alluringly simple, but unless the Java VM must be started up anyway, that startup cost is considerable; doesn't perform well with large line counts either.

Answer (score 1):

This bash function has the minimal dependency(only sort and bash):

```
shuf() {
while read -r x;do
    echo $RANDOM$'\x1f'$x
done | sort |
while IFS=$'\x1f' read -r x y;do
    echo $y
done
}
```

Comment: Nice bash solution that parallels the OP's own `awk`-assisted solution, but performance will be a problem with larger input; your use of a single `$RANDOM` value shuffles correctly only up to 32,768 input lines; while you could extend that range, it's probably not worth it: for instance, on my machine, running your script on 32,768 short input lines takes about 1 second, which is about 150 times as long as running  `shuf` takes, and about 10-15 times as long as the OP's own `awk`-assisted solution takes. If you can rely on `sort` being present, `awk` should be there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In windows You may try [this batch file](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/3rdpartybatchfiles.php#Shuffle) to help you to shuffle your data.txt, The usage of the batch code is

```
C:\> type list.txt | shuffle.bat > maclist_temp.txt
```

After issuing this command, maclist_temp.txt will contain a randomized list of lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work for large files. I gave up after 2 hours for a 1million+ lines file

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned as of yet:

1. The [`unsort`](https://git.fruit.je/unsort) util.  Syntax (somewhat playlist oriented):

   ```
   unsort [-hvrpncmMsz0l] [--help] [--version] [--random] [--heuristic]
          [--identity] [--filenames[=profile]] [--separator sep] [--concatenate] 
          [--merge] [--merge-random] [--seed integer] [--zero-terminated] [--null] 
          [--linefeed] [file ...]
   ```
2. [`msort`](http://www.billposer.org/Software/msort.html) can shuffle by line, but it's usually overkill:

   ```
   seq 10 | msort -jq -b -l -n 1 -c r
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` variant:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# usage:
# awk -f randomize_lines.awk lines.txt
# usage after "chmod +x randomize_lines.awk":
# randomize_lines.awk lines.txt

BEGIN {
  FS = "\n";
  srand();
}

{
  lines[ rand()] = $0;
}

END {
  for( k in lines ){
    print lines[k];
  }
}
```