# Randomly shuffling lines in Linux / Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have some files in linux. For example 2 and i need shuffling the files in one file.

For example

```
$cat file1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
```

and

```
$cat file2
linea one
linea two
linea three
linea four
linea five
linea six
linea seven
linea eight
```

And later that i shuffling the two files i can obtain something like:

```
linea eight
line 4
linea five
line 1
linea three
line 8
linea seven
line 5
linea two
linea one
line 2
linea four
line 7
linea six
line 1
line 6
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I shuffle the lines of a text file in Unix command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line)

Answer (score 163):

You should use `shuf` command =)

```
cat file1 file2 | shuf
```

Or with Perl :

```
cat file1 file2 | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -wne 'print shuffle <>;'
```

Comment: Note that `cat` wouldn't be needed if there was only one file : `shuf file` would do the job.

Answer (score 66):

Sort: (similar lines will be put together)

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -R
```

Shuf:

```
cat file1 file2 | shuf
```

Perl:

```
cat file1 file2 | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle<STDIN>'
```

BASH:

```
cat file1 file2 | while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf "%06d %s\n" $RANDOM "$line"
done | sort -n | cut -c8-
```

Awk:

```
cat file1 file2 | awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}' | sort -n | cut -c8-
```

Comment: Please don't use `sort -R` for this task unless you're sure all the lines are distinct (see my comment for Kent's answer).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf of course - theyre sorted by the hash key - same line = same hash key...

Comment: Hello down voter. Would be nice to know how to improve the answer.

Comment: `shuf` performs best, followed by the `perl` solution; the `awk` solution, while noticeably slower, has the advantage of being POSIX-compliant. `sort -R`, as mentioned, is not a true shuffle, and also quite slow with large input. Using a `bash` loop is slowest by far, and here also hampered by only producing a max. of 32,768 random values. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30133294/45375) for a more detailed performance comparison.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf so `sort -Ru` x)

Answer (score 25):

Just a note to OS X users who use MacPorts: the `shuf` command is part of `coreutils` and is installed under name `gshuf`.

```
$ sudo port install coreutils
$ gshuf example.txt # or cat example.txt | gshuf
```

Comment: For non MacPorts: `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to use pipes here. Sort alone does this with the file(s) as parameters. I would just do

```
sort -R file1
```

or if you have multiple files

```
sort -R file1 file2
```

Comment: c'mon too easy and directly answers the OP to boot. need to make things harder than this.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a one-liner that doesn't rely on `shuf` or `sort -R`, which I didn't have on my mac:

```
while read line; do echo $RANDOM $line; done < my_file | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

This iterates over all the lines in `my_file` and reprints them in a randomized order.

Answer (score 8):

I would use `shuf` too.

another option, gnu sort has:

```
   -R, --random-sort
          sort by random hash of keys
```

you could try:

```
cat file1 file2|sort -R
```

Comment: Be careful with the `sort -R` method: similar lines will be put together (try it with, e.g., twice the same file, you'll be surprised).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thx for pointing that out. yes, it is from hashing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It employs the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

```
randomize()
{   
    arguments=("$@")
    declare -a out
    i="$#"
    j="0"

while [[ $i -ge "0" ]] ; do
    which=$(random_range "0" "$i")
    out[j]=${arguments[$which]}
    arguments[!which]=${arguments[i]}
    (( i-- ))
    (( j++ ))
done
echo ${out[*]}
}


random_range()
{
    low=$1
    range=$(($2 - $1))
    if [[ range -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo $(($low+$RANDOM % $range))
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}
```

Comment: just a note: you don't need to use `$` in bash arithmeric expansion.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly biased rand (like half the time the list will start with the first line) but for some basic randomization with just bash builtins I guess it is fine? Just print each line yes/no then print the rest...

```
shuffle() {
    local IFS=$'\n' tail=
    while read l; do
        if [ $((RANDOM%2)) = 1 ]; then
            echo "$l"
        else
            tail="${tail}\n${l}"

        fi
    done < $1
    printf "${tail}\n"
}
```