# Unix: ls to select all files, but in a random order?

Tags: unix, ls

Since `ls` returns the files in alphabetical order, is there a way to return the same files but in a random order? I am trying to loop through all the files in a directory, but would like it to differ in separate runs.

```
for i in *.py # Would like order to be random
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [randomly shuffling files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578873/randomly-shuffling-files-in-bash) and [How can I shuffle the lines of a text file on the Unix command line or in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-on-the-unix-command-line-or-in-a-shel)

However, this should do the job:

```
for i in `ls *.py | shuf`
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Be aware, this will error if there are no python files in the folder.

Comment: This is similar but it will succeed even if there are filenames with `\n` ...
`find . -name \*.py -print0 | shuf -z | xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c 'for i ; do printf "%s\n" "${i}" ; done' notusebutmandatory`