# bash shell pull all values from array in random order. Pull each value only once

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, random

I need to pull the values from an array in a random order. It shouldn't pull the same value twice.

```
R=$(($RANDOM%5))
mixarray=("I" "like" "to" "play" "games")
echo ${mixarray[$R]}
```

I'm not sure what to do after the code above. I thought of putting the first pulled value into another array, and then nesting it all in a loop that checks that second array so it doesn't pull the same value twice from the first array. After many attempts, I just can't get the syntax right.

The output should be something like:
to
like
I
play
games

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple method to shuffle the elements of an array in BASH shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533569/simple-method-to-shuffle-the-elements-of-an-array-in-bash-shell)

Comment: See [how to randomly loop over an array (shuffle) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53229380).

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

mixarray=("I" "like" "to" "play" "games")
mapfile -t result < <(for (( i = 0; i < ${#mixarray[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo -e "${RANDOM}\t${i}"
done | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f2 | while IFS= read -r n; do
    echo "${mixarray[$n]}"
done)
echo "${result[*]}"
```

- First, it prints a random number and an index starting with 0 side by side.
- The procedure above is repeated as much as the length of `mixarray`.
- The output will look like:

```
13959   0
6416    1
6038    2
492     3
19893   4
```

- Then the table is sorted with the 1st field:

```
492     3
6038    2
6416    1
13959   0
19893   4
```

- Now the indices in the 2nd field are randomized. The field is extracted with
  the `cut` command.
- Next rearrange the elements of `mixarray` using the randomized index.
- Finally the array `result` is assigned with the output and printed out.