# How to sort randomly (shuffle) file lines efficiently?

Tags: sorting

`sort` has a `--random-sort` option, but this option makes `sort` significantly slower:

```
# time sort --random-sort input >/dev/null

real    0m7.247s
user    0m7.232s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Without `--random-sort`, it's 10 times faster:
(`input` is not previously sorted)

```
# time sort input >/dev/null

real    0m0.625s
user    0m0.616s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Why is this so slow ? Is their a way to shuffle a file's lines efficiently ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I shuffle the lines of a text file in Unix command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [`shuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf). It should be faster since it is dedicated to the job.

Comment: I should add that `shuf` loads the entire input file in memory, so it's not always suitable.

Comment: @arnaud576875: I don't think that's avoidable without doing multiple passes through the file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try awk to select random lines in a file, an example (I do not test the performance):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} 
     END{
         srand(); 
         for(j=0; j<100; j++) {
             i=int(rand()*NR+1);
             print a[i];
         }
     }'
```