# A script for generating a mapping between two sets of words randomly

Tags: shell, awk, sed, mapping

E.g. the inputs are two sets A and B.

set A is stored in file `a.txt` as below:

```
apple
orange
grape
...
```

set B is stored in file `b.txt` as below:

```
tomato
potato
cucumber
...
```

The output is `c.txt` like:

```
apple    potato
orange   tomato
grape    celery
...      ...
```

Note the mapping between them is randomly generated. I.e., each time

```
map.sh a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

usually give a different mapping.

Can this be implemented in shell (or awk, sed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste <(shuf a.txt) <(shuf b.txt)
```

If you would like the first column to stay constant, you can simply supply `a.txt` as the first argument to `paste`:

```
paste a.txt <(shuf b.txt)
```

Comment: works perfectly on linux. Thanks, Tim. Any alternatives for mac environment?

Comment: @JackWM: AFAIK, OS X should have the `paste` utility installed with the system.

Comment: Yes. It has paste, but no `shuf`

Comment: @JackWM:  You could try replacing `shuf <filename>` with `sort -R <filename>`.

Comment: It seems it doesn't support `sort -R` either. But I found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line

Comment: +1, no chance to use the command shuf, here is a good sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you *did* want to do this in Awk, you could use `rand()`. Just make sure you set a new random seed (`srand()`) each time:

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { srand() }
    NR == FNR {
        a[rand(), NR] = $1; 
        next;
    } 
    1 == FNR { asorti(a, v) } 
    {
        i = length(v); 
        j = v[i];
        delete v[i]; 
        print $1, a[j];
    }
' a.txt b.txt

tomato orange
potato apple
cucumber grape

$ awk ' BEGIN { srand() }
    NR == FNR {
        a[rand(), NR] = $1; 
        next;
    } 
    1 == FNR { asorti(a, v) } 
    {
        i = length(v); 
        j = v[i];
        delete v[i]; 
        print $1, a[j];
    }
' a.txt b.txt

tomato apple
potato orange
cucumber grape
```