# Shell programming: Select random line from command output

Tags: macos, shell

I'm trying to create a simple Shell script which involves selecting a random directory from the current working directory, and navigating to it.

**Can anyone illustrate how to list all directories, and from this list, randomly select one?**

I'm trying to avoid listing all directories to a text file and simply selecting a random line from that file (which is simple enough).

My initial attempts included using the `ls -d */` command to list only directories. This command worked when it was entered into the terminal, however returned the error:

```
ls: */: No such file or directory
```

when I tried to implement it into this script:

```
DIR_LIST=` ls -d */`

echo "$DIR_LIST"
```

Comment: You might specify OSX as a tag...

Comment: alternatives to `shuf` are listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path . | shuf -n 1`

---

No `shuf` version:

```
# To exclude hidden directories, use -name like so:
# find ... -name ".*"

# A version of find using only POSIX options:
# This might be slower for large directories (untested). Will need to be modified to list anything other than current directory.
# dirs="$(find . -type d ! -path "./*/*" ! -name ".")"

# Includes hidden directories.
dirs="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path .)"

numlines="$(printf "%s\n" "${dirs}" | wc -l)"
lineno="$((${RANDOM} % ${numlines} + 1))"
random_line="$(printf "%s\n" "${dirs}" | sed -n "${lineno}{p;q}")"

echo "Your selected directory: ${random_line}"
```

**Edit:** Improved code based on comments.

Comment: Works well; it's worth pointing out that the `find` command returns _hidden_ subdirectories too, unlike glob `*` (at least by default); a number of optimizations are possible: `shuf | head -n 1` can be simplified to `shuf -n 1`, as demonstrated by Rajesh N's answer. Similarly, `head -n ${lineno} | tail -n 1` can be simplified to `sed -n "${lineno}p"` (or `sed -n "${lineno}{p;q;}` for max. efficiency). POSIX `echo`doesn't support any options, so given that this question is generically tagged `shell`, `printf '%s\n'` can be used in place of `echo -E` to make the non-`shuf` code POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and kudos for the POSIX-compliant `find` command, but note that a simple `find * -prune -type d` would do the trick in this case (solves both the issue of limiting traversal depth and excluding hidden dirs.).
Of course, since that relies on the _shell_'s pathname-expansion mechanism anyway, you could 
just use `dirs=$(printf '%s\n' */)` - which is arguably the simplest (and equally POSIX-compliant) solution in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The **error message** you're seeing indicates that the **current directory *happens* to have *no* (non-hidden) subdirectories** - the script's working directory is probably different from what you expect - `cd` to the desired dir. first.

Aside from that, however, it's better [not to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs);
using [pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) *directly* is both simpler and more robust - see below.

<sup>Note: Originally, this answer contained only one solution, based on a `bash` *array*, which has been replaced with multi-line-string solutions, given the generic title of the question.</sup>

---

The question is tagged `osx`, which has two implications:

- GNU utility `shuf` is NOT preinstalled.

  - However, you can install it (as `gshuf`) via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with `brew install coreutils`.
- BSD utility `jot` IS preinstalled; while far from being the equivalent of `shuf`, it *is* capable of choosing a random number from a range of integers.

---

A **`jot`-based** solution:

```
dirs=$(printf '%s\n' */)  # collect subdir. names, each on its own line
randomLineNum=$(jot -r 1 1 $(wc -l <<<"$dirs")) # pick random line number
randomDir=$(sed -n "$randomLineNum{p;q;}" <<<"$dirs") # extract random dir. name
cd "$randomDir"    # use the randomly selected dir.
```

- `printf '%s\n' */` prints all directory names (with a terminating `/`); each on its own line.

  - Note that there is *no* good reason to use `find` in a simple case like this; the glob `*/` is sufficient to match all subdirectories.
- `jot -r 1 1 $(wc -l <<<"$dirs")` returns a randomly chosen integer between 1 and the number of lines in `$dirs` (`wc -l <<<"$dirs"`), i.e., the number of subdirs.
- `sed -n '<lineNumber>{p;q;}'` is a `sed` idiom that prints (`p`) only the line with the specified number and then quits (`q`) processing the file.

---

A **POSIX-compliant solution**:

Note: This can be handy if you cannot assume the presence of `jot`,`shuf`, or even `bash`.

```sh
dirs=$(printf '%s\n' */)
randomLineNum=$(awk -v count="$(printf '%s\n' "$dirs" | wc -l)" \
                  'BEGIN { srand(); print 1 + int(rand()* count) }')
randomDir=$(printf '%s\n' "$dirs" | sed -n "$randomLineNum{p;q;}")
cd "$randomDir"
```

- `printf '%s\n' "$dirs" | wc -l` counts the number of lines in `$dir`
- `awk -v count=<lineCount> 'BEGIN { srand(); print 1 + int(rand()* count) }'` uses `awk` to print a random number between 1 and :

  - `srand()` seeds the random generator, and `rand()` returns a random float >= 0 and < 1; by multiplying with the line count, converting to an integer and adding 1, a random number >= 1 <= line count is returned.

---

For the sake of completeness, let's look at `shuf` solutions:

---

**Simplest, but inefficient** solution using **`shuf`**:

```
printf '%s\n' */ | shuf -n 1
```

- `shuf -n 1` shuffles all input lines and then prints only the *first* of the shuffled lines.

This is inefficient, because even though only *1* random line is needed, **`shuf` invariably reads all input lines *at once* into memory**, and shuffles *all* of them instead of just picking 1 random one; with a small number of lines that probably won't matter, however.

---

**Slightly more cumbersome**, but **more efficient `shuf`** solution:

Note that this solution is similar to the `jot`-based one above.

```
dirs=$(printf '%s\n' */)
randomLineNum=$(shuf -n 1 -i 1-"$(wc -l <<<"$dirs")")
randomDir=$(sed -n "$randomLineNum{p;q;}" <<<"$dirs")
cd "$randomDir"
```

- `shuf -n 1 -i 1-"$(wc -l <<<"$dirs")"` shuffles *integers* in the range between 1 and the count of lines in `$dirs` (`wc -l <<<"$dirs"`), and prints only *one* (the first) `-n 1` of the shuffled numbers, effectively yielding a single, random line number.
- Shuffling only the range of line *numbers* rather than the *lines themselves* will typically be more efficient, but note that a random permutation of *all* integers in the range is still built up in memory - unlike with `jot`, which simply picks a *single* integer in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls -d */ | shuf -n 1
```

**shuf** selects random directory from your output.

Your script will look like this:

```
DIR_LIST=`ls -d */`
echo "$DIR_LIST" | shuf -n 1
```

Comment: ++1 for `shuf -n 1`; as noted, `shuf` is a _GNU_ utility that is typically only preinstalled on _Linux_ distros. It won't make much difference in many cases, but I suggest replacing `ls -d */` with `printf '%s\n' */` for both better performance and better robustness.

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

instead of using ls. I'm not at a terminal right now so I cannot test. It might be maxdepth 0.

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` is correct, but you _also_ need `-mindepth 1` (or `! -path .`, as in @sorbet's answer) to prevent inclusion of `.`