# How to move X number of files randomly in Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

How can I move 100 random files from one directory to another in the Mac terminal? I would use shuf in linux.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959939/7552

Answer (score 1):

Based on glenn's commend, here's the answer (this would move 100 random files in the current directory):

```
shuf -zen100 * | xargs -0 -J % mv % /New_Dir/
```