# How to find random files in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

How to pick 100 files randomly from a directory by Linux shell. I read other topic, 'shuf' command can do this: find . -type f | shuf -n100, but our environments do not have 'shuf' cmd. Is there other method to do this? use bash, awk, sed or sth else?

Comment: The challenge in POSIX shell is you have no array to provide a simple correlation between existing filename and random index. While there are several solutions with `awk` and via a brute force script, your must have a method that will handle (skip) duplicate random numbers generated within the range of the number of files. (which in itself is an additional challenge without a convenient array). That said, does your `sort` command provide the `-g` and `-u` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on your CentOS5:

```
shuf() { awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand()"\t"$0}' "$@" | sort | cut -f2- ;}
```

This comes from a comment by Meow on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153889/5844347

Use like so: `find . -type f | shuf | head -100`

Answer (score 2):

You can get a directory listing, then randomize it, then pick the top *N* lines.

```
ls | sort -R | head -n 100
```

Replace `ls` with an appropriate `find` command if you want a recursive listing or need finer control of the files to be included.

Comment: No -R option for 'sort' under CentOS 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To get a integer number between 1 to 100 :
N=`echo|awk 'srand() {print 99*rand() + 1 }' | sed -e "s/\..*$//g"`
echo $N

# To get the Nth file :
find . -type f  | head -${N} | tail -1

# To get 100 files randomly :
for i in $(seq 1 100 )
N=`echo|awk 'srand() {print 99*rand() + 1 }' | sed -e "s/\..*$//g"` 
find . -type f  | head -${N} | tail -1
done
```