# Shuffling pairs of lines in two text files

Tags: nlp, shuffle, training-data

I'm working on a machine translation project in which I have 4.5 million lines of text in two languages, [English](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/data/wmt14.en-de/train.en) and [German](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/data/wmt14.en-de/train.de). I would like to shuffle these lines prior to dividing the data into shards on which I will train my model. I know the `shuf` command described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-on-the-unix-command-line-or-in-a-shel/30133294) allows one to shuffle lines in one file, but how can I ensure that corresponding lines in the second file are also shuffled into the same order? Is there a command to shuffle lines in both files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

- `paste` to create separate columns from two files into a single file
- `shuf` on the single file
- `cut` to split the columns

**Paste**

```
$ cat test.en 
a b c
d e f
g h i

$ cat test.de 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

$ paste test.en test.de > test.en-de

$ cat test.en-de
a b c   1 2 3
d e f   4 5 6
g h i   7 8 9
```

**Shuffle**

```
$ shuf test.en-de > test.en-de.shuf

$ cat test.en-de.shuf
d e f   4 5 6
a b c   1 2 3
g h i   7 8 9
```

**Cut**

```
$ cut -f1 test.en-de.shuf> test.en-de.shuf.en
$ cut -f2 test.en-de.shuf> test.en-de.shuf.de

$ cat test.en-de.shuf.en 
d e f
a b c
g h i

$ cat test.en-de.shuf.de
4 5 6
1 2 3
7 8 9
```