# Select Random file by extention then select "connected" files

Tags: file, unix, random

OK, I am stumpped.  I need a shell Script that will randomly select a file with the extention of .sct.  The using a portion of its file name select the six related .mot files.  Then move them all to another folder.  I also need a user input for the number of files to randomly select.

So I have a file structure like this:

```
123-12345-00.sct
123-12345-00.mot
123-12345-01.mot
123-12345-02.mot
123-12345-03.mot
123-12345-04.mot
123-12345-05.mot

123-12346-00.sct
123-12346-00.mot
123-12346-01.mot
123-12346-02.mot
123-12346-03.mot
123-12346-04.mot
123-12346-05.mot
```

And so on.  Need to randomly select the file .sct and move it and its related files to another directory.  Hopefully I have explained this good enough.

Thanks for the help.  I could do this in VB but this UNIX thing has me stumpped.  Right now we do it manualy through thousands of files.

Scott

Comment: Maybe ideas can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414164/how-can-i-select-random-files-from-a-directory-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

This script moves the `123-12345-*.sct` and `123-12345-*.mot` files to a directory named `123-12345` and so on.

**Note: This does not randomly select a file, but all files within the directory.** You can modify this to accept a command line argument for the number of random files. Then you'll need to modify this command `ls [0-9]*.sct | grep -oe '[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{5\}'` to use your command line argument which is a count of files and return a random number of prefixes.

Copy the below to a file, say `mv_sct_mot.sh` within the  same directory as your sct and mot files.

```
#!/bin/bash

for prefix in `ls [0-9]*.sct | grep -oe '[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{5\}'`; do
  mkdir -p ${prefix};
  mv ${prefix}-*.{mot,sct} ${prefix};
done
```

To make the file executable modify it's permission like:

```
chmod +x mv_sct_mot.sh
```

Run it like:

```
./mv_sct_mot.sh
```

Comment: Why do you pick the mot files to discard them later on? And also: Where does the random part come in?

Comment: Edited for clarity regarding random part. The mot files are not discarded. They are moved to the target directory.

Comment: I meant: The ls selects all .sct and .mot files where it would suffice to select only .sct files. When there are no double .sct files(double meaning like: 123-12345-00.sct and 123-12345-01.sct) you don't even have to sort and uniq this way.

Comment: You are right, it is unnecessary to select the mot files. This would avoid duplicate prefixes and we can do away with the sort and uniq entirely. Thank you Nobody :-). Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I am trying to use it now.  I put the code in exactly as it is written and I get "No such Directory" error.  I am missing something easy I ma sure.  As I may have mentioned this is outside my comfort zone.

Comment: Scott: I'm guessing this is probably because you do not have write permission for mkdir command to work. Would be more helpful if you can post a pastie of the complete error.

Comment: Ocaj, Unfortunatly I only have internet access on the Windows machine.  The error is as i wrote.  and I am using the larger code sample.  Do both of them need to be combined? Do I need to include anything else?  I can make a directory in the 
Thanks Again-- Scott

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can run this command from the terminal separately `ls [0-9]*.sct | grep -oe '[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{5\}'` to see the sct file `prefixes` it grabbed. Then run `mkdir -p prefix` with any one of the `prefixes` the previous command grabbed to create the directory. Run the final command to move the mot and sct files within the directory you created with `mv prefix-*.{mot,sct} prefix`. Don't forget to substitute `prefix` with one of the `prefixes` from the output of first command. This way you can figure out which command is creating problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

dir="$1"
count="$2"

[ "$dir" ] && [ $count -gt 0 ] && {

    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then echo "$0: $dir: no such directory"; exit; fi;

    RANDOM=$(date +%s)                      #init random seed

    for (( c=0; c < $count; c++ )); do

        files=(*.sct)                       #creates array of sct files
        ct=${#files[@]}                     #computes array length

        if [ $ct -eq 0 ]; then break; fi    #no more .sct file, exiting

        sct=${files[$[($RANDOM % $ct)]]}    #pick random file

        # You might want to change this according to your file names
        # Everything before the last dash `-' (included) will be taken
        # as prefix
        prefix=$(echo $sct | sed 's:\(.*-\).*:\1:')

        mot_files=($prefix*.mot)            #creates array of all matching .mot

        mv $sct $dir                        #moves .sct to $dir
        if [ ${#mot_files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
            mv ${mot_files[@]} $dir         #moves each matching .mot to $dir
        fi

    done

} || echo "usage: $0 <dir> <num of files>"
```

Would do it.

---

```
/tmp/r > ls
123-12345-00.mot  123-12345-05.mot  123-12346-04.mot
123-12345-00.sct  123-12346-00.mot  123-12346-05.mot
123-12345-01.mot  123-12346-00.sct  123-12348-00.mot
123-12345-02.mot  123-12346-01.mot  123-12348-00.sct
123-12345-03.mot  123-12346-02.mot  foo
123-12345-04.mot  123-12346-03.mot
/tmp/r > mkdir bar
/tmp/r > ./foo bar 2
/tmp/r > ls
123-12346-00.mot  123-12346-02.mot  123-12346-05.mot
123-12346-00.sct  123-12346-03.mot  bar
123-12346-01.mot  123-12346-04.mot  foo
/tmp/r > ls bar
123-12345-00.mot  123-12345-02.mot  123-12345-05.mot
123-12345-00.sct  123-12345-03.mot  123-12348-00.mot
123-12345-01.mot  123-12345-04.mot  123-12348-00.sct
```

Comment: +1 : Awesome! Scott you owe Bertrand a bottle of the best champagne! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
#!/bin/bash
## use the first param as count (1 as default value)
count=${1:-1}
## list all .sct files, random sort and pick the first $count
ls $SRCDIR/*.sct | sort -R | head -n $count | 
    while read file; do
        ## for each file, figure out the prefix and move prefix*
        prefix="${file%-*}-"
        mv -v $prefix* $DESTDIR
    done
```

EDIT: I initially missed the part where the number of files is a parameter, updated the script now. I skipeed the part where you set SRCDIR and DESTDIR just for clarity.