# Randomly select a file with a given extension and copy it to a given directory

Tags: bash

I would like to write a simple bash script that randomly selects a `.flac` file from the `/music/` folder (it will have to be recursive because there are many subfolders within that folder), and copy that file to `/test/random.flac`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414164/how-can-i-select-random-files-from-a-directory-in-bash) is very close to what I want to do but I'm not sure how to change the script to do what I want.

I tried this:

```
ls /music |sort -R |tail -1 |while read file; do
    cp $file /test/random.flac
done
```

But I'm missing how to tell `ls` to do a recursive search of all the `.flac` inside the subfolders.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what's causing you difficulties, retrieving the files, or selecting a random one?

Comment: @Verv I added my attempt to modify the script from the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shove all the files into an array, then select one at a random index to move. This requires the [`globstar` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) to be enabled so you can use the `**/*` glob pattern:

```
shopt -s globstar
flacfiles=(/music/**/*.flac)
cp "${flacfiles[RANDOM % ${#flacfiles[@]}]}" /test/random.flac
```

To select a random index, we take [`$RANDOM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-RANDOM) modulo the number of elements in the `flacfiles` array.

If you want an error message in case the glob doesn't match anything, you can use the `failglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar failglob
if flacfiles=(/music/**/*.flac); then
    cp "${flacfiles[RANDOM % ${#flacfiles[@]}]}" /test/random.flac
fi
```

This fails with an error message

```
-bash: no match: music/**/*.flac
```

in case there are no matching files and doesn't try to copy anything.

If you know for sure that there are `.flac` files, you can ignore this.

Comment: @Inian I've added a version using `failglob`.

Answer (score 3):

## Recurse

Use `find` instead of `ls`:

```
find /music/ -iname '*.flac' -print0 | shuf -z -n1
```

The `find` part will find all flac files inside the directory `/music/` and list them.
`shuf` shuffles that list and prints the first entry (which is random, because the list was shuffled).

`-print0` and `-z` are there to use `\NUL` for separating the file names. Without these options, `\n` (newline) would be used, which is unsafe, because filenames can contain newlines (even though it is very uncommon).

## Copy

If you want to copy just one random file, there's no need for a `while` loop. Use Substitution `$()` instead.

```
cp "$(find /music/ -iname '*.flac' -print0 | shuf -z -n1)" /test/random.flac
```