# Looping through a random set of files

Tags: bash, loops

I have a random set of files that I want to loop over (e.g. so I can copy or move). I am using the command `shuf` using a bash function.

`inclnm` customarily contains a wildcard for specific files, e.g.

`( -name A\* -o -name B\*.mse )`.

Here is the random listing command that I would like to loop through.

```
shuf -n $nf < <( find $dpath -maxdepth 1 -type f "${inclnm[@]}" )
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Pipe the output of `shuf` to a `while read filename` loop

Comment: Or pipe it to `xargs` to pass them all as arguments to another command.

Comment: Thought about a `for fl in $( shuf ... ); do`.  But there could be more sensible way. With the for loop, the find must run to completion, and I can overrun the command line arguments.

Comment: Piping to `while read` is best in case filenames contain spaces. It only fails if filenames contain newlines.

Comment: Thanks.  Have noticed that with a pipe at end of line, I do not need continuation line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select random files from a directory in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414164/how-can-i-select-random-files-from-a-directory-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most rebust option is using null delimited records:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dpath=./
nf=10
inclnm=( -name a\* -o -name b\* )

mapfile -d '' random_files < <(
  find "$dpath" -maxdepth 1 -type f "${inclnm[@]}" -print0 |
  shuf -z -n "$nf"
)

# Debug
declare -p random_files
```

Or alternatively replacing `find` with `printf`:

```sh
inclnm=( a* b* )

cd "$dpath" || :
mapfile -d '' random_files < <( printf %s\\0 "${inclnm[@]}" | shuf -z -n "$nf" )
```

Or even better, let `shuf` work on arguments directly and no need for `printf` or `find`:

```sh
mapfile -d '' random_files < <( shuf -z -n "$nf" -e "${inclnm[@]}" )
```

Note that this last method will be subject to the max argument length restriction.